# Still getting an error "ImportError: No module named win32com.client" after installing pywin32 lib

Tags: python

I already installed the "Python for Windows extensions" library from here:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/

but when I import the "win32com.client" in my program, I still got the error message:

```
ImportError: No module named win32com.client
```

My Python version is 3.2.

Any ideas?

Comment: check the paths to libraries, find out where it has been installed
and can python find it (right now it can't)

Comment: Follow @Nicola 's suggestion,I add "win32com" into the pywin32.pth file under the _site-packages_ of (Python3.2),but my program still can not find it.                                                                              My system have multi-version of Python (Python2.5,Python3.1,Python3.2),I set Python3.2 into the _WINDOWS Environment variables_ , so when I check **sys.path** under the PYTHON SHELL, it show the environment is Python3.2, but if I write `import sys  print (sys.path)` in a .py file and run it, it will show the environment is Python2.5. I don't know why they are different.

Comment: But finally, I resolve this problem by indicating the specific version of python.exe.  for example, I run my .py file like this `c:\Python32\python.exe test.py`

Comment: [\[SO\]: ImportError: No module named win32com.client (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75310161/4788546)

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem while using Visual Studio. The following fixed the issue:
1. Right Click Project Properties (in the Solution Explorer window)
2. Select Properties
3. In the General Tab set the appropriate Interpreter (Python2.7 in this case)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check `sys.path` to make sure the directory where the module is installed is in there, otherwise you have to add it (google `PYTHONPATH windows` for some help with that.)

Answer (score 0):

For some reason win32com is not included in `pywin32.pth` under `site-packages`. You might try and add it there, but [this post about Movable Python](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/movpy/reference/win32ext.html) makes me think that the problem is a bit more complicated.