# ImportError: No module named win32com.client

Tags: python, excel, win32com

I am currently using python 2.7 and trying to open an Excel sheet.
When using the code below:

```
import os
from win32com.client import Dispatch

xlApp = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
xlApp.Visible = True
# Open the file we want in Excel
workbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open('example.xls')
```

I get this error:

> ImportError: No module named win32com.client

Is there any possibility of getting the error since I am using 64-bit Windows machine?

Comment: Just checking, did you install the extensions: http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/
It is **not** a standard library.

Comment: Your question has been answered here: http://superuser.com/questions/609447/how-to-install-the-win32com-python-library and here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7978510/why-i-already-installed-pywin32-lib-but-still-got-importerror-no-module-named

Comment: Note that the above code gives an error even if the win32com is installed right. The 3rd line must be xlApp = Dispatch("Excel.Application")

Comment: pip install pywin32 pypiwin32 winshell

Answer (score 186):

`pip install pywin32` didn't work for me but `pypiwin32` did.

Comment: If you can't find pip on the command line, this works too:
    'python -m pip install pypiwin32'

Comment: None of these worked for me. I tried both pypiwin32 and pywin32 and they both didn't work.

Comment: I get an error: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32>=223 (from pypiwin32) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pywin32>=223 (from pypiwin32) although I'm on Python 2.7.10 - does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: @MACC Having the same issue, but I'm running two versions of python and I think they're getting confused. Did you ever figure it out?

Comment: Note that pypiwin32 is an [old and outdated repacking of pywin32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55918311/what-is-the-difference-between-pywin32-and-pypiwin32).

Answer (score 31):

`win32com.client` is a part of **pywin32**

So, download pywin32 from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pywin32)

Comment: pywin32 is a dependency of pypiwin32

Comment: pip often does not run the post installation script, so manual install is the solution

Answer (score 23):

Try this command:

```
pip install pywin32
```

**Note**

*If it gives the following error:*

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32>=223 
>   (from pypiwin32) (from versions:)
>   No matching distribution found for pywin32>=223 (from pypiwin32)

upgrade 'pip', using:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

Answer (score 14):

I realize this post is old but I wanted to add that I had to take an extra step to get this to work.

Instead of just doing:

```
pip install pywin32
```

I had use use the `-m` flag to get this to work properly. Without it I was running into an issue where I was still getting the error `ImportError: No module named win32com`.

So to fix this you can give this a try:

```
python -m pip install pywin32
```

This worked for me and has worked on several version of python where just doing `pip install pywin32` did not work.

Versions tested on:

3.6.2, 3.7.6, 3.8.0, 3.9.0a1.

Answer (score 12):

Try both `pip install pywin32` and `pip install pypiwin32`.

It works.

Answer (score 7):

You must install the package `pywin32`:

```
pip install pywin32
```

After installation `import win32com.client`

Python has the “Python for Windows Extensions” package known as `pywin32` that allows us to easily access Window’s Component Object Model (COM) and control Microsoft applications.

Answer (score 5):

Had the exact same problem and none of the answers here helped me.
Till I find [this thread and post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49307408)

Short: win32 modules are not guaranted to install correctly with pip.
[Install them directly from packages provided by developpers on github](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/releases).
It works like a charm.

Answer (score 4):

***Win32COM* is (and was always) part of *PyWin32***.

#### 1. *PyWin32*

[[GitHub]: mhammond/pywin32 - Python for Windows (pywin32) Extensions](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32) is a *Python* wrapper over *WinAPI*s).
Documentation (*WiP*) can be found at [[GitHub.MHammond]: Python for Win32 Extensions Help](https://mhammond.github.io/pywin32) (or [[ME.TimGolden]: Python for Win32 Extensions Help](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/contents.html)).

Lately, binaries (*.whl*s) are published on [[PyPI]: pywin32](https://pypi.org/project/pywin32) (starting with ***v222*** (from *20180121*) - there are a couple of older records, but they don't contain any (useful) packages).

As many other software, it was previously hosted on [[SourceForge]: mhammond - Python for Windows Extensions](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32).
Binaries ((*.exe*) installers):

- Were released there as well

  - Last one: ***v221*** (from *20170329*)
- Are also available on *GitHub* (but they are **deprecated**)

#### 2. *PyPIWin32*

Only exists on [[PyPI]: pypiwin32](https://pypi.org/project/pypiwin32).

**Currently** (at answer time), there are only 3 versions:

1. *v219* (from *20141203*):

   - Contains *.whl*s for various *Python* versions
2. *v220* (from *20170112*):

   - Only contains *.whl*s for *Python 3.6*
3. *v223* (from *20180226*):

   - Only contains one *.whl* **with no data** (but having *PyWin32* as a dependency)

Also check Mark Hammond's answer: [[GitHub]: mhammond/pywin32 - Add CascadeWindows wrapper (@mhammond's comment)](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/pull/1999#issuecomment-1407799954) (**emphasis** is mine):

> It existed before pywin32 itself supported being packaged as a wheel. **I don't think it has much current value**, but presumably there are still things out there that depend on it? TBH, I can't even recall who created it as I guess that's who we should ask (but know it wasn't me!)

From the above, one can only conclude that *Py**PI**Win32* was just a playground for testing the newly introduced *.whl* packaging scheme, and now (maybe excepting the 1<sup>st</sup> version) is just garbage.

As a consequence:

#### Do NOT install *PyPIWin32* (<s>`pip install pypiwin32`</s>)

**Installing *PyWin32* is all you need: `python -m pip install pywin32`** (one could also target a specific (*PyWin32*) version).

If it doesn't work after that, there are other issues.
Here are a couple of links with potential problems (and ways to overcome them), generic advice, and so on:

- [[SO]: How to install a package for a specific Python version on Windows 10? (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57883242/4788546)
- [[SO]: PyCharm doesn't recognize installed module (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73363599/4788546)
- [[SO]: How to update pywin32 automatically? (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49499867/4788546)
- [[SO]: PyWin32 and Python 3.8.0 (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58632354/4788546)
- [[SO]: PyWin32 (226) and virtual environments (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58805300/4788546)
- [[SO]: Install win32com on MacOs and Linux (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65030870/4788546)
- [[SO]: Can't import dll module in Python (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59333711/4788546)
- [[SO]: Python Ctypes - loading dll throws OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57297745/4788546)

Answer (score 3):

I'm using Visual Studio Code on a 64-bit laptop using Windows.  I eventually got this to work!  First install pywin32 as normal:

```
python -m pip install pywin32
```

If you're using Code Runner, you may need to make sure that you have the right path to your module in your code:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("C:\\_path_to_virtual_environment\\Lib\\site-packages\\")

import win32com.client as win32
```

Now change directory in your terminal windows to your scripts folder and run this:

```
python pywin32_postinstall.py -install
```

This will change your error message to say you're missing the win32api module.  To get this, install this:

```
python -m pip install pypiwin32
```

I wouldn't say I had a profound insight what all these commands do, but it (finally) solved my problem!

Comment: `python -m pip install pywin32` worked for me on 64 bit Windows and Python 3.11.2

Answer (score 2):

in some cases where pywin32 is not the direct reference and other libraries require pywin32-ctypes to be installed; causes the "ImportError: No module named win32com" when application bundled with pyinstaller.

running following command solves  on python 3.7 - pyinstaller 3.6

```
pip install pywin32==227
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to install the "pywin32" file, you can find in https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/releases

Install the version that you use in your IDLE, and try to install, after you can open your project and compile another turn!

thanks !

Answer (score 0):

### ImportError: No module named win32com.client

1. **Open Command prompt in admin mode**
2. **Install win32com.client**

   a. By pip install method

   ```
    pip install win32
    If this throws error: version of win32 not determined then try installing via b. By pypi install method
   ```

   b. By pypi install method

   `python -m pip install pywin32`

3.**Add program path to the python path**

Answer (score -1):

if you have to already installed library and still getting error. you need to check in which folder the library got installed and copy paste it to the correct folder.

Library should be installed in same directory to the python.