# Strange error while using Pycharm to debug PyQt gui

Tags: python, debugging, pyqt, pycharm, pydev

I've been using PyCharm to debug my gui in PyQt. This has been really successful thus far, until I've run into a strange error in trying to debug my gui just now. I've set a breakpoint at the beginning of the script as well as at various points but the program does not have a chance to get to this point. I've also tried removing all the breakpoints and running the debug but get the same result. The full traceback is:

```
C:\Users\pbreach\Continuum\Anaconda3\python.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2016.3\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py" --multiproc --qt-support --client 127.0.0.1 --port 53720 --file C:/Users/pbreach/Dropbox/FIDS/cci/bluebook/code/input.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2016.3\helpers\pydev\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_cython_wrapper.py", line 2, in <module>
    from _pydevd_bundle.pydevd_cython import trace_dispatch, PyDBAdditionalThreadInfo
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pydevd_bundle.pydevd_cython'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2016.3\helpers\pydev\pydevconsole.py", line 8, in <module>
    from code import InteractiveConsole
ImportError: cannot import name 'InteractiveConsole'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2016.3\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 26, in <module>
    from _pydevd_bundle.pydevd_additional_thread_info import PyDBAdditionalThreadInfo
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2016.3\helpers\pydev\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_additional_thread_info.py", line 17, in <module>
    from _pydevd_bundle.pydevd_cython_wrapper import PyDBAdditionalThreadInfo
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2016.3\helpers\pydev\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_cython_wrapper.py", line 26, in <module>
    mod = __import__(check_name)
  File "_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_cython_win32_36_64.pyx", line 9, in init _pydevd_bundle.pydevd_cython_win32_36_64 (_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_cython_win32_36_64.c:21388)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2016.3\helpers\pydev\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_frame.py", line 10, in <module>
    from _pydevd_bundle.pydevd_breakpoints import get_exception_breakpoint
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2016.3\helpers\pydev\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_breakpoints.py", line 15, in <module>
    from _pydevd_bundle.pydevd_comm import get_global_debugger
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2016.3\helpers\pydev\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_comm.py", line 75, in <module>
    import pydevconsole
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2016.3\helpers\pydev\pydevconsole.py", line 10, in <module>
    from _pydevd_bundle.pydevconsole_code_for_ironpython import InteractiveConsole
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2016.3\helpers\pydev\_pydevd_bundle\pydevconsole_code_for_ironpython.py", line 105
    except SyntaxError, err:
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Does anyone know what is causing this error and how it can be resolved? When I run the code normally (without debugging) I do not run into any of these errors.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I ran into the same issue, and it took me a while but I found a solution that works for me.  I believe what happens, is that the debugger is looking for the module `_pydevd_bundle.pydevd_cython` in a directory `code`.  However, because you are running the script out of your own `code` directory, the debugger checks your folder, sees their is no module, and throws the error.  That would explain why deleting the `__init__.py` works, because the debugger won't confuse the two directories anymore.

So, renaming your code directory to something else, should fix the issue and let you keep the init file.

Comment: Amazing that you figured that out! I went through the source but could not figure that out. Thanks!

Comment: this works. In my case it was a file, code.py, probably created by jupyter/ipython notebook plugin

Comment: Wonderful answer.

Comment: Brilliant .. In fact my file name was `code` and got the same issue.

Comment: Great, very hard the find the fix, even if it's very small. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I've recently hit this issue (while working on [[SO]: zipfile.BadZipFile: Bad CRC-32 when extracting a password protected .zip & .zip goes corrupt on extract (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55063500/4788546)). 
As a note, I used to name my code snippets *code.py*, unless otherwise constrained (now I use *code00.py*, as it's more generic and I can increment the number at the end if I have more than one file).

### *Python*

According to [[Python.Docs]: Modules - The Module Search Path](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path) (**emphasis** is mine):

> When a module named *spam* is imported, the interpreter first searches for a built-in module with that name. If not found, it then searches for a file named `spam.py` in a list of directories given by the variable [sys.path](https://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.path). [sys.path](https://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.path) is initialized from these locations:
>
> - **The directory containing the input script (or the current directory when no file is specified)**.
> - [PYTHONPATH](https://docs.python.org/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH) (a list of directory names, with the same syntax as the shell variable *PATH*).
> - The installation-dependent default.

Little demo:

> ```
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q042705279]> set py
> PYTHONPATH=E:\Work\Dev\Utils
>
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q042705279]> dir /b
>
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q042705279]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.06.08_test0\Scripts\python.exe"  -c "import code;print(code)"
> <module 'code' from 'c:\\Install\\x64\\Python\\Python\\03.06.08\\Lib\\code.py'>
>
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q042705279]> echo. 2>code.py
>
>
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q042705279]> dir /b
> code.py
>
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q042705279]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.06.08_test0\Scripts\python.exe"  -c "import code;print(code)"
> <module 'code' from 'e:\\Work\\Dev\\StackOverflow\\q042705279\\code.py'>
> ```

As seen (under normal circumstances), if the module ***code*** (applies to packages as well) is found in *cwd*, it's loaded from there. 
The *code* module (*code.py*) is not randomly chosen (read the next section). Check [[Python.Docs]: code - Interpreter base classes](https://docs.python.org/library/code.html) for details about one part of the standard *Python* library.

### *PyCharm*

When **running** a *PyCharm* configuration, *PyCharm* (simplified) launches project interpreter on the configured script. This works. In my case it's:

> ```
> "E:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.06.08_test0\Scripts\python.exe" "E:/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q042705279/code.py"
> ```

However when **debugging** the same configuration, things are a bit more complicated. The simplified version:

- A server is created (by *pydevd*) that executes the target script
- *PyCharm* *IDE* connects to that server in order to get output

Again, in my case it's:

> ```
> "E:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.06.08_test0\Scripts\python.exe" "C:\Install\x64\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition\AllVers\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py" --multiproc --qt-support=auto --client 127.0.0.1 --port 45931 --file "E:/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q042705279/code.py"
> ```

The **key point** is somewhere at the beginning of ***pydevconsole.py*** (which is mentioned in the exception traceback):

```py
try:
    from code import InteractiveConsole
except ImportError:
    from _pydevd_bundle.pydevconsole_code_for_ironpython import InteractiveConsole
```

So, it tries to load the *InteractiveConsole*, which (obviously) fails. 
Apparently, the *code* module is specific to ***C**Python*. Its absence means that it another distribution (check [[Python]: Alternative Python Implementations](https://www.python.org/download/alternatives)). 
The *IPython* alternative (selected by default) contains scripts that are not *Python 3* (syntactically) compliant (at the current point [IronPython](https://ironpython.net) is at *v**2.7**.9*). Note that this happens before even reaching user code. 
Switching the interpreter to *Python 2* won't help either, it will pass this point, but later it will also try to setup the interactive console, which will fail.

### Conclusion

- Don't have any module / package named *code* in your *sys.path* (before *Python*'s standard paths)
- Apparently *pydevd.py* has other arguments, but a quick check didn't reveal any possibility of using them to get around this issue
- **I was able to successfully debug my *code.py*** file (from *PyCharm*), by changing the *Working directory* from configuration settings. But I consider this a (lame) workaround (*gainarie*), and for complex setups it **might not even work**

[[SO]: PyCharm doesn't recognize installed module (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73363599/4788546) might also contain some useful info.