# Pycharm Debug mode syntax error

Tags: python, pycharm

all of a sudden when running PyCharm Community edition i've started to get this syntax error when running debug mode.  I tried reinstalling PyCharm but had no luck with the error.  Anyone see this before?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 26, in <module>
    from _pydevd_bundle.pydevd_additional_thread_info import PyDBAdditionalThreadInfo
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_additional_thread_info.py", line 19, in <module>
    from _pydevd_bundle.pydevd_additional_thread_info_regular import PyDBAdditionalThreadInfo  # @UnusedImport
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_additional_thread_info_regular.py", line 5, in <module>
    from _pydevd_bundle.pydevd_frame import PyDBFrame
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_frame.py", line 10, in <module>
    from _pydevd_bundle.pydevd_breakpoints import get_exception_breakpoint
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_breakpoints.py", line 15, in <module>
    from _pydevd_bundle.pydevd_comm import get_global_debugger
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_comm.py", line 75, in <module>
    import pydevconsole
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevconsole.py", line 10, in <module>
    from _pydevd_bundle.pydevconsole_code_for_ironpython import InteractiveConsole
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/_pydevd_bundle/pydevconsole_code_for_ironpython.py", line 105
    except SyntaxError, err:
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: You appear to have gotten Python 2 files and a Python 3 interpreter mixed up somehow.

Comment: In about 20 years of professional programming I have never solved a syntax error by reinstalling the IDE.

Comment: [pbreach's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42737548/376258) worked for me

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about any project specific configurations or run configurations:

1. quit pycharm
2. delete `.idea` folder in your project folder
3. start pycharm

I've used this method as a quick fix solution when I encountered this issue late last night. But, the very nature of this solution indicates that this issue is caused by some corruption in the `.idea` folder. Were I to encounter this problem again, I would suggest a different approach:

1. first, try to search for the error text in the files in the `.idea` folder
2. if the previous step fails:

   1. quit pycharm
   2. move the `.idea` folder inside the project folder to a safe location
   3. start pycharm to create a fresh `.idea` folder and quit it again
   4. preform a 3-way merge between the old and the new `.idea` folders
   5. start pycharm

Answer (score 1):

If you have `__init__.py` in your current path, delete it.
Or if your file name is `code.py`, rename to something else.