# How PyCharm imports differently than system command prompt (Windows)

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, pycharm, directory

I am having a problem running my script in a cmd prompt despite it working in PyCharm. I have a folder structure as such:

```
MyCode # PyCharm project folder
  /UsefulFunctions
    /Messaging
      /Texter.py
  /DiscordBot
    /DiscordBot.py
```

Within DiscordBot.py I have an import

```
from UsefulFunctions.Messaging import Texter
```

This works when I run it from PyCharm without a problem. However when I try to run from a command prompt located at the `DiscordBot` level it errors with:

> ImportError: No module named 'UsefulFunctions'

So naturally I thought it meant that the `UsefulFunctions` folder was not on my path. Therefore, I went into my environment variables and added it to my `PATH` variable (as well as the `MyCode` folder for good measure). Still it encountered this error. I browsed some posts on here regarding imports (mainly [Importing files from different folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder/4383597#4383597)) and they recommend doing something like:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/path/to/application/app/folder')
import file
```

Or adding `__init__.py` files to each folder in order to get them to register as packages. I went ahead and added `__init__` files to each folder and subfolder I was trying to import from, but still could not run from the command prompt...I ommitted the `sys.path.insert()` solution because I see no benefit from this after already explicitly adding it to my `PATH` variable. Another solution was to add "." before the import because supposedly otherwise it is only searching python's PATH. I attempted this as:

```
from .UsefulFunctions.Messaging import Texter
```

> ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

And this error shows on PyCharm now as well... I don't get why my initial script would work without a hitch on PyCharm, but the same program cannot seem to find my import when run from a prompt. Can somebody please explain the difference between PyCharm running the program and my prompt? Why will this not work despite having `__init__.py` files **and** having added `MyCode` and `UsefulFunctions` to my PATH variable on Windows?

Comment: What happens when you try `import UsefulFunctions.Messaging.Texter as Texter`?

Comment: @LukeNing the same `ImportError` unfortunately :(

Answer (score 7):

From [[Python.Docs]: Command line and environment - PYTHONPATH](https://docs.python.org/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH):

> Augment the default search path for module files. The format is the same as the shell’s PATH: one or more directory pathnames separated by [os.pathsep](https://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.pathsep) (e.g. colons on Unix or semicolons on Windows). Non-existent directories are silently ignored.

You can also find more details on [[SO]: Strange error while using Pycharm to debug PyQt gui (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55066132/4788546).

So, in order for *Python* to be able to load a module (package) without specifying its path, the path must be present in *%PYTHONPATH%* environment variable.

You mentioned *%PATH%* several times in the question but it's ***%PYTHONPATH%*** (*MyCode* must be added to it).

*PyCharm* does that because of (any of) the 2 checkboxes in the image below (dialog can be triggered from the menu: ***Run** -> **Edit Configurations...***):

[image: Img0]

If you want to get things working from *CmdLine*, yo have to do the same thing there as well:

> ```
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q054955891\DiscordBot]> sopr.bat
> ### Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ###
>
> [prompt]> set py
> Environment variable py not defined
>
> [prompt]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.06.08_test0\Scripts\python.exe" DiscordBot.py
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "DiscordBot.py", line 1, in <module>
>     from UsefulFunctions.Messaging import Texter
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'UsefulFunctions'
>
> [prompt]> set PYTHONPATH=e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q054955891
>
> [prompt]> set py
> PYTHONPATH=e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q054955891
>
> [prompt]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.06.08_test0\Scripts\python.exe" DiscordBot.py
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q054955891\UsefulFunctions\Messaging\Texter.py imported
> ```

Conversely, in *PyCharm* (with the *content roots* related checkbox from above, checked), more content roots can be added like in the image below (menu: ***File** -> **Settings...***, select *Project Structure* then *Add Content Root*):

[image: Img1]

This is useful when some required modules are located deeper in the project tree (and some *dir*s aren't valid *Python* package names).

So, when dealing with this type of situation, checking [[Python.Docs]: sys.path](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path), [[Python.Docs]: os.getcwd()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.getcwd) and module path, can save lots of wasted time and headaches:

```py
import os
import sys

print(sys.path)
print(os.getcwd())

import some_module
print(some_module)
```

As a side note, I personally hate names starting with *My* (e.g. *MyCode*). Such a name tells me that the purpose of whatever entity "wears" it, was not clear to the person who wrote the code. Try finding a more useful name (e.g. *TestBotProject*, or *smth* similar) :).

[[SO]: PyCharm doesn't recognize installed module (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73363599/4788546) might also contain some useful info.

Comment: Too bad I did not see the bouty 13 hours ago ^^ This is exactly what I would have answered first: `Run/Debug configuration` has special default behavior. In addition, if each module of the OP is somewhat standalone, defining all necessary `__init__.py` looks like the pythonic thing to do too ?

Comment: @LoneWanderer: The bounty shouldn't be the reason for posting an answer :). If you feel you have something which would add value, please go ahead and post it. If wanting t play by the rules, adding the *\_\_init\_\_.py* in each dir should be done. But as you have seen it works without them as well.

Answer (score 3):

Check your Interpreter. It is different than your command prompt Interpreter, located in `Appdata`, whereas the interpreter for PyCharm is in the `Workspace` folder.

Comment: How would I check my interpreter and be able to get them to match so the command prompt can run the script though?

Comment: Go to File>Settings>Interpreter Settings
If it is using the python file of your project as an interpreter like 'C:\Users\Riyouk\PycharmProjects\untitled1\venv\Scripts\python.exe'. Change it to python installed in your appdata folder whose address is more likely 'C:\Users\Riyouk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe'

Answer (score 3):

Python uses the system variable `PYTHONPATH`, among other things, to decide what to import.
From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path):

> When a module named spam is imported, the interpreter first searches
>   for a built-in module with that name. If not found, it then searches
>   for a file named spam.py in a list of directories given by the
>   variable sys.path. sys.path is initialized from these locations:
>
> - The directory containing the input script (or the current directory
>     when no file is specified).
> - PYTHONPATH (a list of directory names,
>     with the same syntax as the shell variable PATH).
> - The installation-dependent default.

The reason PyCharm magically imports the module when you run the script is because of the `Project Structure -> Content Root` value. It points to your project directory, by default.

Comment: I'm not sure how to check my `PYTHONPATH` but I ran `set path=%PATH%;%PYTHONPATH%;` at command prompt and then my program still did not run due to the same `ImportError`. How is it possible for me to achieve the same behavior with command prompt that I can get with PyCharm's magical "Content Root" value (which I wasn't able to see under "Project Structure" tab of the settings menu in PyCharm)?

Comment: The issue is that `PYTHONPATH` is empty (check with `echo %PYTHONPATH%`). You need to set it to your project's directory full path, `MyCode` to enable importing from that project from anywhere (in this case, `DiscordBot`). If you want this setting to persist, you must set it as a system environment variable using `setx`. That requires you run cmd as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

Set your Python path  in System variables,So that you can run python -help from any where in directory
then 
navigate to  project folder

```
c:\nnnn..\mmm..\MyCode 
run python  c:\nnnn..\mmm..\MyCode\DiscordBot
    \DiscordBot.py
```

or

```
C:\Python27\python.exe "C:\Users\Username\MyCode\DiscordBot
    \DiscordBot.py" or 
C:\Python27\python.exe C:\Users\Username\MyCode\DiscordBot
    \DiscordBot.py
```

Try quotes if path  has space