# PyCharm Comunnity Edition

Tags: python, pycharm

File `senha`:

```
def seu_token():
      return'your token pass'
```

File `main`:

```
import discord
import random
from senha import seu_token
```

PROBLEM: When I use the `from import` or `import` the importation doesn't occur. I tested and found that all the imports I make from a file that I made have this problem. If I try to import from another file/lib/API, it works normally.

ALREADY TRY:
All type of import, Create a New Project only to test the imports and really doesn't work. Re-install PyCharm, Re-code files, ask on Groups for Help and until now, no solution.

Comment: Can you also show the directory tree of your project (where the files are located relative to one another), and whether you have a file called `__init__.py` or not?

Comment: does the senha.py file is in the root directory of the project or in a separate package?

Comment: @MihaiChelaru The files are in the same directory C:(...)\Python\BOTv2\Main\Vital. I do not have a file called __init__.py, i used python a year ago, basically I rewrite the codes and used the same way for the imports.

Comment: What do you mean by "*the importation doesn't occur*"? Do you get any error? Also, did you try `from .senha import seu_token`?

Comment: Yes i tried @CristiFati. And I think that I found accidentally the answer. The directory wasn't in Source Root, I'm testing and I will post the answer soon. Thanks anyway.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54955891/how-pycharm-imports-differently-than-system-command-prompt-windows/55083046#55083046?

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new project in *PyCharm* You are working by default in a **virtual environment** that just have the basic python packages.

Just open the terminal in *PyCharm* and install the packages you need via `pip`/`pip3`.Don't worry, if you have them installed in your computer you will fetch the packages from the cache automatically.

Or just exit the virtual environment by typing in the *Pycharm* terminal as `deactivate` and you will be able to use the local packages.