# pychrm cannot import my own package, but the terminal can

Tags: python, import, pycharm

**Problem solved.**
If you add your path to PYTHONPATH, you can import the packages inside that path. But what I am doing is try to import that path, this is wrong.
So in this case, I make a sub Dir at my path and that dir is now a package can be imported.
Still I have to include my path in **file>settings>project structure** as source.

==========================================================================
I am using python3.6 in anaconda, Ubuntu16.04.
I have my own package in path /home/gph/pyutils_gph.
Inside this dir are utils.py files. I have include this path in PYTHONPATH.
I can do

```
Python 3.6.8 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Dec 30 2018, 01:22:34) 
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from pyutils_gph import utils
>>>
```

in terminal. But the same import code shows error in pycharm. It can find my package, indicating it with red lines.
What else should I do to make pycharm know my own package?

==========================================================================

I opened the terminal inside pycharm, get output like below. I have that dir in PYTHONPATH, but I can not import it. What's wrong?

```
Python 3.6.8 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Dec 30 2018, 01:22:34) 
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/home/gph/pyutils_gph', '/home/gph/Desktop/BorderSecure/detection_cnn/src', '/home/gph/anaconda3/envs/py36_torch0.4/lib/python36.zip', '/home/gph/anaconda3/envs/py36_torch0.4/lib/python3.6', '/home/gph/anaconda3/envs/py36_torch0.4/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/home/gph/anaconda3/envs/py36_torch0.4/lib/python3.6/site-packages']
>>> from pyutils_gph import utils
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyutils_gph'
>>>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PyCharm error: 'No Module' when trying to import own module (python script)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28705029/pycharm-error-no-module-when-trying-to-import-own-module-python-script)

Comment: Try invalidate cache and restart pycharm.

Comment: I think [\[SO\]: How PyCharm imports differently than system command prompt (Windows) (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54955891/how-pycharm-imports-differently-than-system-command-prompt-windows/55083046#55083046) might help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How PyCharm imports differently than system command prompt (Windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54955891/how-pycharm-imports-differently-than-system-command-prompt-windows)

Comment: what do you have in folder `'/home/gph/pyutils_gph'`  ? Is it `'/home/gph/pyutils_gph/pyutils_gph.py'` ? If not then probaly you have to add `/home/gph/` instead of  `/home/gph/pyutils_gph` to `PYTHONPATH`. If you have `/home/gph/pyutils_gph/utils.py` and you add `/home/gph/pyutils_gph` then you have to do `import utils`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `/home/gph/pyutils_gph` in `PYTHONPATH`  and you do `from pyutils_gph import utils` then it is looking for

```
"/home/gph/pyutils_gph/" + "pyutils_gph/utils.py`
```

because `from pyutils_gph import utils` means `pyutils_gph/utils.py` and it adds it to every path from `PYTHONPATH`

---

You have to add to `PYTHONPATH`

```
/home/gph
```

and then it will give

```
"/home/gph/" + "pyutils_gph/utils.py`
```

so you get correct path

---

First version can works in terminal if you run Anaconda in folder `/home/gph` because `Python` search packages also in current working directory so it finds `pyutils_gph/utils.py` directly in `/home/gph` without using `PYTHONPATH`

If you will go to different folder then it will not find local `pyutils_gph/utils.py` and you get the same error.

Comment: Thanks for ur answer. But I can do `from pyutils_gph import utils` in terminal without any errors.

Comment: because probably you run Anaconda in `/home/gph` - so it looks for subfolder `pyutils_gph` in current working directory. Go to different folder and it will not work in terminal.