# ModuleNotFoundError when running the code outside PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I have a module called `my_module.py` which is under the directory `test/my_modules/my_module.py`.

When I am trying to import that module in a different module using:

```
from test.my_modules.my_module import something
```

everything seems to be OK when running the code from PyCharm but when running the code outside PyCharm I get the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'test'
```

PS: Using Python 3.6 so `__init__.py` shouldn't be required in every module.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54955891/how-pycharm-imports-differently-than-system-command-prompt-windows/55083046#55083046

Answer (score 0):

The working directory of PyCharm and the one where you are running the code outside of PyCharm are different. Hence, it does not find the module `test` anymore.

You need to change the relative path, where you want to import it from or add the folder, where the module `test` is located to your `PYTHONPATH` environmental variable, so that Python can find it.