# No module found error when I have added the path

Tags: python, module, path

I have a project structure that looks like:

[image]

The file `greet.py` is given as:

```
def greet_morning(message):
    print("Hello, {}", message)

def greet_evening(message):
    print("Evening message: {}", message)
```

and the file `msg.py` is given as :

```
import sys
import os
sys.path.append(os.getcwd())


from greet.greet import greet_morning

greet_morning("heyy")
```

When I try to run `msg.py` as `python message/msg.py`, I get an error saying `ImportError: No module named greet.greet`. I am running this file from the root. Why do I get this error, when I have already added the `cwd` in the system path?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Importing files from different folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54955891/how-pycharm-imports-differently-than-system-command-prompt-windows/55083046#55083046

Answer (score 1):

I think is

```
from untitled.greet.greet import greet_morning
```

if still doesnt work, add:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('../')
```

> edit

I think you may find all the possible solutions here [Importing files from different folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder)

Comment: It still gives an error `ImportError: No module named untitled.greet.greet`

Comment: After I added `__init__.py` in all directories, it works but with `from greet.greet import greet_morning`. I had to remove `untitled`. Could you help me understand this?

Comment: @Amanda , yes, basically you are making visible your parallel modules by adding them into the sys.path

Comment: Will I need to do this in all the files inside the project?

Answer (score 1):

[image]add `__init__.py` inside greet and msg folder__init__.py

Answer (score 0):

You have missed the file `__init__.py` in your module.

Just create an empty file `__init__.py` in greet folder.

Comment: ```
import sys
import os
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath('../greet'))
import greet

greet.greet_morning("heyy")
```