# Python ModuleNotFoundError despite __init.py__ and correct PYTHONPATH on Linux

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, ubuntu

I'm trying to get a Python script running on my Ubuntu server. I have the following directory structure:

```
/home/pythontest
      |_  __init__.py
      |_  main.py
      |_  module_a.py
```

inside module_a.py:

```
def print_a():
    print('a')
```

inside main.py:

```
from pythontest.module_a import print_a
def execute():
    print_a()
execute()
```

When I run main.py in PyCharm on my Windows machine, it prints `a` as expected, on my Linux machine, when I call `python3 main.py` I get a

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
        from pythontest.module_a import print_a
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pythontest'
```

The `__init__.py` exists (and is completely empty) and I have added the directory /home/pythontest to the PYTHONPATH with the following command:

```
export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/home/pythontest"
```

(testing this with `echo $PYTHONPATH`also yields the correct path)

Additional Notes:
 - The python3 version on my machine is **Python 3.6.9**
 - My Server runs **Ubuntu 18.04** 
 - All those files are written in PyCharm on Windows and copied over via SSH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're importing *pythontest*(*.module_a*), which is located in */home*. That's what you're supposed to add to *PYTHONPATH*:

```bash
export PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:/home
```

More details on [[Python.Docs]: The import system](https://docs.python.org/reference/import.html#the-import-system).

Or you could not reference the package name from within it (consider *relative imports*):

```py
from .module_a import print_a
```

Might also want to check [[SO]: How PyCharm imports differently than system command prompt (Windows) (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55083046/4788546), to see why does it work from *PyCharm*.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your `import` in `main.py` to:

```
from module_a import print_a
```

since `module_a` is a module that exists in the path that you exported.