# Django ImportError: No module named 'culqipy'

Tags: python, django

I made a module for Python https://github.com/culqi/culqi-python
but I don't know the reason why I cannot import it into my Django project.

```
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/willyaguirre/PycharmProjects/e-s/tienda/urls.py", line 4, in <module>
    from . import views
  File "/Users/willyaguirre/PycharmProjects/e-s/tienda/views.py", line 13, in <module>
    import culqipy as culqi
ImportError: No module named culqipy
```

Maybe my module is not correct.

Comment: Are you sure that you've installed that package in right environment?

Comment: I think the problem is with PyCharm IDE I will check it

Comment: I think is fixed the problem was with my version of Python https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31235376/pycharm-doesnt-recognise-installed-module

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have installed it in the virtual environment of your current project. Or make sure you have activated the correct virtual environment for your project.