# How to install Python using the "embeddable zip file"

Tags: python, pycharm

I downloaded the **Windows x86-64 embeddable zip file** from **https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-365/**.

(I cannot use the executable/web-based installer on my computer)

I want to install this on my PyCharm. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are 2 main steps (each with its own set of substeps) that need to be followed:

1. Download and unpack the interpreter on your machine:

   1. Download the *.zip* file (e.g. [[Python]: python-3.6.5-embed-amd64.zip](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.5/python-3.6.5-embed-amd64.zip)) on your computer, in an empty dir (on my machine it's: *"e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q050818078\python36x64"*)
   2. Unzip the file (some (*.pyd*, *.dll*, .*exe*, *.zip*, *._pth*) files will appear). At the end, you can delete the *.zip* file that you downloaded in previous step
2. Configure *PyCharm* to use it:

   **Notes**:

   - In order for the images below to be a small as possible (from size and display *PoV*), I have reduced the sizes of all windows from their default values
   - Some *PyCharm* stuff is specific to my machine / environment, (obviously) that will be different in your case
   - The script that I used for testing, is a dummy one that just prints some paths (that's why I didn't add it as code, it's just in the 1<sup>st</sup> image)
   - I only illustrate the minimal required steps to get you going, so even if for some steps there are options to customize them, I'm not going to mention them
   - I am using *PyCharm Community Edition 2017.3.3* (in other versions things could be slightly different)

   **Steps**:

   1. In *PyCharm* main window (considering your project is open), go to menu ***File** -> **Settings...***:

      [image: Img0]

      You could also go to ***File** -> **Default Settings...***, check [[JetBrains]: Project and IDE Settings](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/project-and-ide-settings.html) for differences between them.
   2. In the ***Settings*** window, click ***Project Interpreter** -> **Show All*** (you might need to scroll down - if you have multiple interpreters configured)

      [image: Img1]
   3. In the ***Project Interpreters*** window, click the ***Add*** button (green ***+*** (*plus*) on upper right side). Also, you might have to click an ***Add Local...*** control that appears when you click ***Add***

      [image: Img2]
   4. In the ***Add Local Python Interpreter***, make sure to:

      - Check ***Exiting environment*** radio button
      - Click the ***...*** (*Browse*) button

      [image: Img3]
   5. In the ***Select Python Interpreter*** window, go to the folder where you unzipped the file at ***#1.1.***, select *python.exe* and then click ***OK***

      [image: Img4]
   6. Click the ***OK*** button in all the windows opened at previous steps (in reversed order), until you're back to main window

In order to test, on the code editor window, right click and from the popup menu choose ***Run 'code'***. Here's console output window content:

> ```
> E:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q050818078\python36x64\python.exe E:/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q050818078/src/code.py
> Python 3.6.5 (v3.6.5:f59c0932b4, Mar 28 2018, 17:00:18) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
>
> E:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q050818078\python36x64\python.exe
> E:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q050818078\src\code.py
>
> Process finished with exit code 0
> ```

As a final note, naming the test file ***code**.py* was "a bit" uninspired, as there is such a module in *Python*'s standard library (in the meantime, I renamed it to *code00.py*), but I don't feel like doing all the screenshots (that contain it) again.

[[SO]: PyCharm doesn't recognize installed module (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73363599/4788546) might contain useful info on possible related problems.

Comment: do we get such zip for linux?

Comment: @Mahesha999: Unfortunately, on the *ftp* site I only saw such (prebuilt) downloadables for *Win* and *OSX*.