# conda looking for library outside activate environment

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, conda

I am working on Windows, I find a difference in import behavior about conda created environment which I cannot understand, here the details

Case 1 (Success)

```
(base) C:\> conda activate <env-name>
(env-name) C:\> python
>>> import numpy
(Success)
```

Case 2 (Fail)

```
C:\> cd <path-to-conda-env>
C:\path-to-conda-env> python
>>> import numpy
(Fail)
```

I hit this issue with `ssl` package before, and it can be fixed by install the package from `conda-forge` rather then `default`, so it seem to be a issue with the package

What trouble me is the import statement seem to be loading something outside my conda env as I checked `sys.path` and `sys.executable` is same in both case

What I have missed here? Any input are welcome.

Regards

Comment: The problem can be that there is a python on your system path which will be used when the conda env is not activated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reproduced the problem (identical `sys.path`, which excluded my initial guess: *%PYTHONPATH%*) on my side with *Anaconda 2018.12*. Environment setting (whether it's *Ancaonda*, *VEnv* or any other such tool) consists of (mainly) setting some environment variables.

After testing with some more modules (besides *numpy* and *ssl*), by looking at the errors, I realized that the modules that fail have other *.dll* dependencies of their own. Considering [[MS.Docs]: Dynamic-Link Library Search Order](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/Dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order), I displayed the contents of my *%PATH%* variable inside the *Python* process. On the *conda* enabled version, the paths below were present at the beginning:

> ```py
> >>> import os
> >>> import pprint
> >>>
> >>> pprint.pprint(os.environ["PATH"])
> ('e:\\Install\\x64\\Anaconda\\Anaconda\\2018.12;e:\\Install\\x64\\Anaconda\\Anaconda\\2018.12\\Library\\mingw-w64\\bin;e:\\Install\\x64\\Anaconda\\Anaconda\\2018.12\\Library\\usr\\bin;e:\\Install\\x64\\Anaconda\\Anaconda\\2018.12\\Library\\bin;e:\\Install\\x64\\Anaconda\\Anaconda\\2018.12\\Scripts;e:\\Install\\x64\\Anaconda\\Anaconda\\2018.12\\bin;
> # The rest of the dirs (regular ones)
> ```

Needless to say, that the problem disappeared after prepending those in my *%PATH%* before starting ***normal*** *Python*:

> ```py
> e:\Install\x64\Anaconda\Anaconda\2018.12>set PATH=e:\Install\x64\Anaconda\Anaconda\2018.12;e:\Install\x64\Anaconda\Anaconda\2018.12\Library\mingw-w64\bin;e:\Install\x64\Anaconda\Anaconda\2018.12\Library\usr\bin;e:\Install\x64\Anaconda\Anaconda\2018.12\Library\bin;e:\Install\x64\Anaconda\Anaconda\2018.12\Scripts;e:\Install\x64\Anaconda\Anaconda\2018.12\bin;%PATH%
>
> e:\Install\x64\Anaconda\Anaconda\2018.12>python
> Python 3.7.1 (default, Dec 10 2018, 22:54:23) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
> Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
> >>> import numpy
> >>> import ssl
> ```

But, you should **always follow the recommended way** (especially when not fully aware of what's going on), and that is activating the environment, because even if this works for this scenario, it might not work for others.

***@EDIT0***:

As I specified in one of the comments, in order to add the environment to *PyCharm*, follow the steps from [[SO]: How to install Python using the “embeddable zip file” (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50818078/how-to-install-python-using-the-embeddable-zip-file/50819634#50819634), with some mentions:

- At step ***#4.*** make sure to select "*Conda Environment*" instead of "*Virtualenv Environment*"
- Apparently, the problem persists when launching *Python Console*. It shouldn't be the case, seems like the environment is not set. Maybe it's because I didn't create an environment, I'm simply launching *Python* from the root *Anaconda* installation? Anyway, as a workaround (*gainarie*), I'm applying the same changes (setting *%PATH%*) for the *Python Console* (from "*Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Console -> Python Console*"), as shown in the image below:

  [image: Img00 - Console settings]

  After console restart, everythings works fine.

Comment: After you set *%PATH%*? What is the content of `os.environ["PATH"]`? Hopefully you didn't copy/paste the paths from the answer since they are only valid on my machine. What is the error (edit the question if you must)?

Comment: Thanks, actually I am hitting this issue with 2 scenario 1) with pyCharm 2) with IIS hosting django, both I have no idea how to activate the environment after a quite few search. And with my limited knowledge, it look like something monster to me so asked the question, thanks for the great answer!

Comment: deleted first comment as I saved it in accident, tried to add the PATHs added by conda activate under my envs and everything worked, thanks!

Comment: Here's how to set a *Python* interpreter in *PyCharm*: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50818078/how-to-install-python-using-the-embeddable-zip-file/50819634#50819634. The only difference is that at step ***#4.***, you should select "*Conda Environment*" (instead of *Vitrualenv*), and it should work without any other changes.

Comment: Hi CristiFati, I am good with the interpreter part, the issue is with the Python Console in PyCharm, it will have the same import issue. With your first replay, I am able to find a setting to setup the path before calling the interactive console and that's solved issue on, thanks again!

Comment: I see, I have the same problem. https://medium.com/infinity-aka-aseem/how-to-setup-pycharm-with-an-anaconda-virtual-environment-already-created-fb927bacbe61. I didn't create any env, i just launched the anaconda installation, maybe that is the problem.

Comment: Edited the answer for the *Python Console* problem. It's just a workaround, but it does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You need to activate your environment. 
See that:

```
(base) C:\> conda activate <env-name>
(env-name) C:\> python
>>> import numpy
(Success)
```

There is a `(base)`which means that the active environment name is *based*. 
Try doing
`conda info --envs`

to se a list of environments.

When you do:

```
C:\> cd <path-to-conda-env>
C:\path-to-conda-env> python
>>> import numpy
(Fail)
```

You are navigating to the folder of the environment but you are not using the python environment that it holds.

Try using:

```
which python
```

to see which python version you are using.