# Visual Studio doesn't work with Anaconda environment

Tags: python, visual-studio, anaconda, visual-studio-2019

I downloaded VS2019 preview to try how it works with Python.

I use Anaconda, and VS2019 sees the Anaconda virtual environment, terminal opens and works but when I try to launch 'import numpy', for example, I receive this:

> An internal error has occurred in the Interactive window.  Please
>   restart Visual Studio. Intel MKL FATAL ERROR: Cannot load
>   mkl_intel_thread.dll. The interactive Python process has exited.

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Can you `import numpy` in *Anaconda* *Python* launched "normally" (e.g. from *cmd*)? *AFAIK*, the *mkl* libs are no longer part of *NumPy* (e.g. in *v1.15.4*). Anyway, I think (assuming that your *Python* installation is correct) that's a matter of *%PATH%*.

Comment: Anaconda itself works fine, I'm working in Jupyter\VS code.

Comment: Could you tell me what should I do to check if %PATH% is correct

Comment: You probably entered the path to *python.exe* from *Anaconda* environment. It doesn't work that way (I have a similar error when directly launching it from *cmd*). A new terminal is open by *conda.exe* which sets some vars, and only then you can safely launch *python.exe*. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54303296/conda-looking-for-library-outside-activate-environment/54303755#54303755 for more details (which env vars need to be set). Or you could select *Create conda environment* from *VStudio* (but I think it will download a new *conda* installation).

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue, this worked for me:

***Try to add conda-env-root/Library/bin to the path in the run environment.***