# Apache Zeppelin on Windows: error creating python interpreter

Tags: python, windows, apache-zeppelin

I have tried apache zeppelin on Windows and experience troubles running python interpreter.

When executing a python paragraph it shows an error:

```
org.apache.thrift.TApplicationException: Internal error processing createInterpreter
    at org.apache.thrift.TApplicationException.read(TApplicationException.java:111)
    at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:71)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.thrift.RemoteInterpreterService$Client.recv_createInterpreter(RemoteInterpreterService.java:209)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.thrift.RemoteInterpreterService$Client.createInterpreter(RemoteInterpreterService.java:192)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter$2.call(RemoteInterpreter.java:169)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter$2.call(RemoteInterpreter.java:165)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterProcess.callRemoteFunction(RemoteInterpreterProcess.java:135)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.internal_create(RemoteInterpreter.java:165)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.open(RemoteInterpreter.java:132)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.getFormType(RemoteInterpreter.java:299)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.notebook.Paragraph.jobRun(Paragraph.java:407)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:188)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.RemoteScheduler$JobRunner.run(RemoteScheduler.java:307)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

At that moment I can see in command line output that some path was not found.

```
DEBUG [2019-03-24 18:21:35,717] ({Exec Stream Pumper} RemoteInterpreterManagedProcess.java[processLine]:298) - Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: The system cannot find the path specified
```

Log file directory is empty. Python binaries I try to use are from Anaconda 3 distribution. Zeppelin-env.cmd contains line `set PYTHONPATH=I:\Anaconda3\python;`. Exactly the same is defined in interpreter settings for `zeppelin.python` variable.

Please help to find a way to troubleshoot the error.

Comment: You can't use *Anaconda*'s *Python* directly, without some preps. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54303296/conda-looking-for-library-outside-activate-environment/54303755#54303755. Or you could install a regular *Python* version, and use that one.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you messed up something while you set up it, here you can see the [steps](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/dev-endpoint-tutorial-local-notebook.html) and also [here](https://hernandezpaul.wordpress.com/2016/11/14/apache-zeppelin-installation-on-windows-10/).