# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cryptography.hazmat'; 'cryptography' is not a package

Tags: python, cryptography

This line

```
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
```

is creating this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/crypto/venv/cryptography.py", line 2, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\crypto\venv\cryptography.py", line 2, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cryptography.hazmat'; 'cryptography' is not a package

Process finished with exi
```

Answer (score 7):

You named your file ***cryptography.py***. That conflicts with (and **takes precendence over**) *cryptography* package.

Rename your file name to (something that isn't a well known module / package name) *e.g.* *cryptography_test.py* (consider a valid *Python* identifier name, if you'll ever need to import it from another script), and you should be fine.

More info:

- [[Python.Docs]: Modules](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#modules)
- [[Python.Docs]: The import system](https://docs.python.org/reference/import.html#the-import-system)
- [[SO]: PyCharm doesn't recognize installed module (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73363599/4788546) (for a wider investigation on a related topic)

Answer (score 0):

i was getting that error when i use
from arcgis import GIS

it worked after ive dont this
conda install -c conda-forge protobuf
pip install --no-cache arcgis --user

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).