# Pycharm does not show all installed libraries

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

When I have installed some libraries,the pycharm compiler does not display them.
It displays like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNPTB.png).However I do install some libraries,see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SAfXY.png).And I can use installed moudules like cv2 even though pycharm doesn't show it.What shoud I do to solve it?

Comment: this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31235376/pycharm-doesnt-recognise-installed-module

Comment: Here is some video too https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RvbUqf3Tb1s

Comment: Thank you.But it doesn't help.I run into the problem that I can use libraries I have installed while the pycharm interface(as the first picture in question shows) doen't display it.I can use it normally besides a little inconvent.I guess I ran into some display bugs in pycharm