# I have pip installed the module in my virtual env, but I can not index it

Tags: python, django, pip, virtualenv

I have installed the module:

```
(env) $ pip3 install django-rest-swagger

Successfully installed django-rest-swagger-2.2.0 openapi-codec-1.3.2 simplejson-3.17.0
```

the snapshot:

[image]

My Project Python Interpreter is also the venv:

[image]

Why I can not index it?

Comment: Try [Invalidate Cache](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/cleaning-system-cache.html)

Comment: tied, do not work

Comment: Did you study this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31235376/pycharm-doesnt-recognise-installed-module). It have lot of answers that might can help you :)