# Fibonacci Sequence: Finding Composites Problem

Tags: python, fibonacci

I am looking to find a pair of numbers with a GCD (Greatest Common Denominator) of 1, that the first N terms of the sequence X0, X1, ... XN are all composite.

For my code, for some reason, it gets stuck when i == 15, j == 878, and k == 78.
It gets stuck when running is_prime() on the two last items in the list.

```
import math


def is_prime(num):
    if num < 2:
        return False
    for x in range(2, math.floor(math.sqrt(num)) + 1):
        if num % x == 0:
            return False
    return True


# create list containing a range of composite numbers
numbers = []
for i in range(4, 200):
    if not is_prime(i):
        numbers.append(i)

for i in numbers:
    found = False
    for j in numbers:
        if math.gcd(i, j) == 1:
            # print(i, "-", j, end=" | ")
            fibonacci = [i, j]
            contains_prime = False
            for k in range(2, 500):
                if is_prime(fibonacci[-2] + fibonacci[-1]):
                    contains_prime = True
                    break
                else:
                    fibonacci = [fibonacci[-1], fibonacci[-2] + fibonacci[-1]]
            if not contains_prime:
                print(i, j)
                found = True
        if found:
            break
    if found:
        break
    if i == numbers[-1]:
        print("No Possibilities Exist.")
```

Comment: It's getting stuck because the numbers you're checking are really large, and large numbers take a _really_ long time to factorize.

Comment: maybe have a look at using a better is prime function.

Comment: trial division is the simplest and weakest primality test algorithm there is, because is the slowest of them all for big numbers, you need a more advance algorithm such as Miller–Rabin or Baillie-PSW primality test

Comment: your code get stuck at testing if 51452069511074530979 is prime or not, which is an absurdly big number to test with trial division (its square root is 7173009794)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as I mention in the comments you need a better primality test algorithm, those algorithm can be hard to understand or implement on your own, so you can use a library that offer it instead like `sympy` for example, just install it with pip and use it as:

```
import math
from sympy.ntheory import isprime 

# create list containing a range of composite numbers
numbers = []
for i in range(4, 200):
    if not isprime(i):
        numbers.append(i)

for i in numbers:
    found = False
    for j in numbers:
        if math.gcd(i, j) == 1:
            fibonacci = [i, j]
            contains_prime = False
            for k in range(2, 500):
                if isprime(fibonacci[-2] + fibonacci[-1]):
                    contains_prime = True
                    break
                else:
                    fibonacci = [fibonacci[-1], fibonacci[-2] + fibonacci[-1]]
            if not contains_prime:
                print(i, j)
                found = True
        if found:
            break
    if found:
        break
    if i == numbers[-1]:
        print("No Possibilities Exist.")
```

now is quickly and run without getting stuck and print as result: `143 142`

Comment: It worked flawlessly in my jupyter-notebook, but when I run it in my PyCharm IDE, it does not recognize sympy even though I have it installed. Do you know why this happens?

Comment: If those use their own separate python installation, that might be the cause, otherwise no idea

Comment: Found a temporary fix [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31235376/pycharm-doesnt-recognise-installed-module#:~:text=Solution%3A%20just%20install%20the%20package,you%20will%20see%20it%20pycharm%20.)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your `is_prime` function is to slow, instead of checking if every number is a prime inside of your for loop. Why not generate a list of primes, lets say the first 1 million, store them in a list. Then too check if your number is prime, just check if it is inside of the list.

```
import math

def gen_prime(n):
    D = {}
    q = 2

    for i in range(n):
        if q not in D:
            yield q
            D[q * q] = [q]

        else:
            for p in D[q]:
                D.setdefault(p + q, []).append(p)
            del D[q]

        q += 1

primes = [i for i in gen_prime(1_000_000)]

def is_prime(num):
    if num in primes:
        return True
    else:
        return False

# create list containing a range of composite numbers
numbers = []
for i in range(4, 200):
    if not is_prime(i):
        numbers.append(i)

for i in numbers:
    found = False
    for j in numbers:
        if math.gcd(i, j) == 1:
            # print(i, "-", j, end=" | ")
            fibonacci = [i, j]
            contains_prime = False
            for k in range(2, 500):
                if is_prime(fibonacci[-2] + fibonacci[-1]):
                    contains_prime = True
                    break
                else:
                    fibonacci = [fibonacci[-1], fibonacci[-2] + fibonacci[-1]]
            if not contains_prime:
                print(i, j)
                found = True
        if found:
            break
    if found:
        break
    if i == numbers[-1]:
        print("No Possibilities Exist.")
```

when running this code I get the result

```
18 187
>>>
```

EDIT:
I decided to do some research into prime algorithms, I came across Miller–Rabin.

> The Miller–Rabin primality test or Rabin–Miller primality test is a
> probabilistic primality test: an algorithm which determines whether a
> given number is likely to be prime, similar to the Fermat primality
> test and the Solovay–Strassen primality test.

More information about it can be found on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test).

```
import random, math

# miller_rabin algorithm
def is_prime(n, k = 40):
    if n == 2:
        return True

    if n % 2 == 0:
        return False

    r, s = 0, n - 1
    while s % 2 == 0:
        r += 1
        s //= 2

    for i in range(k):
        a = random.randrange(2, n - 1)
        x = pow(a, s, n)
        if x == 1 or x == n - 1:
            continue

        for i in range(r - 1):
            x = pow(x, 2, n)
            if x == n - 1:
                break

        else:
            return False

    return True

# create list containing a range of composite numbers
numbers = []
for i in range(4, 200):
    if not is_prime(i):
        numbers.append(i)

for i in numbers:
    found = False
    for j in numbers:
        if math.gcd(i, j) == 1:
            # print(i, "-", j, end=" | ")
            fibonacci = [i, j]
            contains_prime = False
            for k in range(2, 500):
                if is_prime(fibonacci[-2] + fibonacci[-1]):
                    contains_prime = True
                    break
                else:
                    fibonacci = [fibonacci[-1], fibonacci[-2] + fibonacci[-1]]
            if not contains_prime:
                print(i, j)
                found = True
        if found:
            break
    if found:
        break
    if i == numbers[-1]:
        print("No Possibilities Exist.")
```

Here is the full code, as you can see when run it returns the result

```
143 142
>>>
```

Comment: the code eventually ask for the primality of number significantly bigger than `10**6` your prime testing function will give false positive/negative for those

Comment: Just increase the the counter `primes = [i for i in gen_prime(1_000_000)]` instead of a million put a billion etc. `gen_prime(1_000_000_000)` or how ever big of a number you want to go up too. Storing the primes in RAM is a **much faster solution**, then looping through and individually checking each number using the OP's original code.

Comment: one of the number it test is 51452069511074530979, generate and store all the primes up to that number (`10**20`) to properly test it does not look like a good idea to me...

Comment: @Copperfield I updated my answer, with a better solution.

Comment: it look good. Personally I prefer the deterministic version

Comment: @Jared Thank you Jared! Copperfield's solution runs much faster as I scale up the numbers, so I decided to accept his answer.