# How to use PyPDF2 in a script?

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

```
import PyPDF2
from PyDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter


file_path="sample.pdf"

pdf = PdfFileReader(file_path)


with open("sample.pdf", "w") as f:'

for page_num in range(pdf.numPages):
   
   pageObj = pdf.getPage(page_num)



   try:
       txt = pageObj.extractText()
       txt = DocumentInformation.author

   except:
       pass

   else:

       f.write(txt)
f.close()
```

Error Received:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyPDF2'

Writing my first ever script where I want to scan in a PDF then extract the text and write it to a txt file. I was trying to use pyPDF2 but I'm not sure how to use it in a script like this.

EDIT: I had success importing the os & sys like so.

```
import os
import sys
```

Comment: Did you insatll the module with pip?

Comment: Yes. 
Successfully installed PyPDF2-1.28.2

Comment: Do you run the script from the console or from your IDE?

Comment: IDE terminal. Have been trying this command python3 Pdf_Extractor.py

Comment: If you are using pycharm, you should read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31235376/pycharm-doesnt-recognise-installed-module

Comment: Will do. Unfortunately I am not though.

Comment: Then how *are* you running the script? Troubleshooting your `sys.path` is a very common FAQ but without details, it's not clear which specific question this is a duplicate of.

Comment: I posted above exactly how I'm running the script an hour before you commented this.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple issues:

1. `from PyDF2 import ...`: A typo. You meant `PyPDF2` instead of `PyDF2`
2. `PdfFileWriter` was imported, but never used (side-note: It's PdfReader and PdfWriter in the latest version of PyPDF2)
3. `with open("sample.pdf", "w") as f:'`: A syntax error
4. Lacking indentation of the next lines
5. Side-note: Did you know that you can simply write `for page in pdf.pages`?
6. `DocumentInformation.author` is wrong. I guess you meant `pdf.metadata.author`
7. You overwrite the `txt` variable - I don't understand why you don't use it before you re-assign it.

Maybe this is what you want:

```py
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader

def get_text(pdf_file_path: str) -> str:
    text = ""
    reader = PdfReader(pdf_file_path)
    for page in reader.pages:
        text += page.extract_text()
    return text


text = get_text("example.pdf")

with open("example.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(text)
```

### Installation issues

In case you have installation issues, maybe [the docs on installing PyPDF2](https://pypdf2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/installation.html) can help you?

If you execute your script in the console as `python your_script_name.py` you might want to check the output of

```bash
python -c "import PyPDF2; print(PyPDF2.__version__)"
```

That should show your PyPDF2 version. If it doesn't, it the Python environment you're using doesn't have PyPDF2 installed. Please note that your system might have arbitrary many Python environments.