# Module not found pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm trying to import a function from another python script that is located in the same folder as my current script but it throws `ModuleNotFound` error.

I checked the path in which Pycharm looks for the module (in this case the spambot.py) and it does look through the current folder for the module so i don't understand why the module isn't found.

[image: Problem]
[image: Path]

Comment: add `__init__.py` file in the same directory. Then you can import specific files.

Comment: `import os`, `print(os.getcwd())` before importing the module, and post the results. https://stackoverflow.com/a/73363599/4788546.

Comment: Also, does it happen with pure Python? Is it something to do with Pycharm?

Comment: @PrakharSharma i added the init python file in the same folder as both the script that contains the function, and also the script that i want to import that function but still the same ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'spambot'. did i create the _init__.py file in the wrong place?

Comment: Ok, have a look at my library [here](https://github.com/praksharma/DeepINN/tree/main/DeepINN/utils). Check how I wrote my `__init__.py`. Just see the import definition, ignore everything after this line `def _load_backend(mod_name):`

Comment: created the file in the same folder as my other scripts. in the init file this is what i tried:
trial 1:
from .spambot import * 
trial 2:
from .spambot import launch
doesnt work for both with the same problem 'unresolved reference: spambot'
but when i tried my solution, posted in the answer section now, it worked. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, when I get your problem.

`from .spambot import launch_chrome`

Answer (score -1):

recap:
i wanted to import a function (named launch) from another script in the same directory (whatsapp folder)

how i solve the problem (though idt its the best solution)

right-click the current directory (whatsapp folder in my case) and create a python package (i name it funcs) in the directory.
in the package, create a **init**.py file. In the init file, put in the functions that you will import on daily basis.

with the above set up, all u need to do is to go to the script u want to import the function and type this:
from (python package) import (function name)
in my case it would be: from funcs import launch
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qBTvZ.png)