# Error after trying to import external libraries in Python : "oserror: (winerror 193) %1 is not a valid win32 application"

Tags: python, python-3.x, winapi, pywin32, oserror

I have the same error when trying to import any external library in Python :

```
import sklearn
```

```
runfile('C:/Users/pc/.spyder-py3/temp.py', wdir='C:/Users/pc/.spyder-py3')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File ~\.spyder-py3\temp.py:1 in <module>
    import sklearn

  File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py:80 in <module>
    from . import _distributor_init  # noqa: F401

  File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\sklearn\_distributor_init.py:22 in <module>
    WinDLL(op.abspath(vcomp140_dll_filename))

  File ~\anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py:382 in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)

OSError: [WinError 193] %1 n’est pas une application Win32 valide
```

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling the libraries first, then did the same for Python. It didn't work.

Comment: You are using a 32-bit binary from 64-bit code, or a 64-bit binary from 32-bit code, or some other architecture mismatch between the callee and library code.

Comment: @IInspectable What can I do about it to solve the problem?

Comment: *"What can I do about it to solve the problem?"* - Match the bitness of all binaries that get loaded into your process. @GinoMempin Running 32-bit binaries on 64-bit versions of Windows is fully supported through the WoW64 emulator.

Comment: How do you run your script? What's its content?

Answer (score 0):

The error is architecture mismatch and is detailed in [[SO]: Python Ctypes - loading dll throws OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57297745/4788546).
So, technically this is a duplicate, but I'm going to dive a bit deeper.

The **root cause** of the error is [[SO]: PyCharm doesn't recognize installed module (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73363599/4788546) (also check referenced *URL*s), **point *#1.*** (and possibly ***#2.***).

There are 2 kinds of paths in the traceback:

1. ***~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39*** - Regular *Python* (*3.9*) installation (possibly from *Windows Store*) - *032bit* (*pc032*). This is the launched interpreter
2. ***~\anaconda3*** - *Anaconda* installation *pc064* (based on the error). This is where the package is loaded from

So you're launching a *Python* instance, and try to load modules from another instance. This is **unsupported** (and it would still be even if everything would work fine).

Now, since the question is not an *MCVE* ([[SO]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)), as it doesn't mention how the code is run (also it would be good to know what environment variables *PATH* or *PYTHONPATH* values are), one can only guess why this situation was reached.

Anyway, to fix this situation (generally), **only use one *Python* instance**.
Specific to this situation, make sure to **launch *Anaconda*'s *Python*** ([[Anaconda.Docs]: Getting started with Anaconda](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/getting-started)).