# Importing .pyd file error "%1 is not a valid Win32 application."

Tags: python, python-3.x, ctypes, dllimport

I'm trying to import .pyd file into python code
the following error is thrown:
"ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _MY_PYD: %1 is not a valid Win32 application."

using python 3.10(64bit) / pyscripter4.1 64bits

I have downloaded and upgraded almost all suggested packages, numpy,winpy32 etc..

What else the issue could be ?

Downloaded and upgraded Python packages
Reinstall of Python and Pyscripter

Comment: Please post the complete traceback and also your *import* statement. Some of your *.dll*s is / are not *064bit*: [\[SO\]: Python Ctypes - loading dll throws OSError: \[WinError 193\] %1 is not a valid Win32 application (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57297745/4788546).

Comment: Also check: [\[SO\]: Error after trying to import external libraries in Python : "oserror: (winerror 193) %1 is not a valid win32 application" (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74319904/4788546), [\[SO\]: Python produces: OSError: \[WinError 193\] %1 is not a valid Win32 application, but only with activate\_this.py (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55734490/4788546).

Comment: how to ask a good question:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask