# ImportError: cannot import name 'OrderedDict' from 'typing'

Tags: python, tensorflow, module, gpu, tensor

```
C:\Users\jpala\.conda\envs\tf\python.exe C:\Users\jpala\Documents\ML\train.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jpala\Documents\ML\train.py", line 5, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "C:\Users\jpala\.conda\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "C:\Users\jpala\.conda\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import data
  File "C:\Users\jpala\.conda\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\data\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.data import experimental
  File "C:\Users\jpala\.conda\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\data\experimental\__init__.py", line 96, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.data.experimental import service
  File "C:\Users\jpala\.conda\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\data\experimental\service\__init__.py", line 419, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.data.experimental.ops.data_service_ops import distribute
  File "C:\Users\jpala\.conda\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\data\experimental\ops\data_service_ops.py", line 25, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.data.ops import dataset_ops
  File "C:\Users\jpala\.conda\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\data\ops\dataset_ops.py", line 29, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.data.ops import iterator_ops
  File "C:\Users\jpala\.conda\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\data\ops\iterator_ops.py", line 34, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.training.saver import BaseSaverBuilder
  File "C:\Users\jpala\.conda\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py", line 32, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.checkpoint import checkpoint_management
  File "C:\Users\jpala\.conda\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\checkpoint\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.checkpoint import checkpoint_view
  File "C:\Users\jpala\.conda\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\checkpoint\checkpoint_view.py", line 19, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.checkpoint import trackable_view
  File "C:\Users\jpala\.conda\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\checkpoint\trackable_view.py", line 20, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.trackable import converter
  File "C:\Users\jpala\.conda\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\trackable\converter.py", line 18, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.eager.polymorphic_function import saved_model_utils
  File "C:\Users\jpala\.conda\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\polymorphic_function\saved_model_utils.py", line 36, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.trackable import resource
  File "C:\Users\jpala\.conda\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\trackable\resource.py", line 22, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.eager import def_function
  File "C:\Users\jpala\.conda\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 20, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.eager.polymorphic_function.polymorphic_function import set_dynamic_variable_creation
  File "C:\Users\jpala\.conda\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\polymorphic_function\polymorphic_function.py", line 76, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.eager.polymorphic_function import function_spec as function_spec_lib
  File "C:\Users\jpala\.conda\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\polymorphic_function\function_spec.py", line 25, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.function.polymorphism import function_type as function_type_lib
  File "C:\Users\jpala\.conda\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\core\function\polymorphism\function_type.py", line 19, in <module>
    from typing import Any, Callable, Dict, Mapping, Optional, Sequence, Tuple, OrderedDict
ImportError: cannot import name 'OrderedDict' from 'typing' (C:\Users\jpala\.conda\envs\tf\lib\typing.py)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I got this error while trying to install and run tensorflow for gpu following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hHWkvEcDBO0
I have python 3.7.4
What am I doing wrong here, is it a version issue?

Comment: Please add the code that you're running. [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Are you sure about *Python 3.7.**4***?  Before `import tensorflow as tf` add `import sys` and `print(sys.version)` and paste the output.

Comment: This [issue in github](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/6904#issuecomment-496207426) may be helpful for Python 3.7.

Comment: when i added that code i got : 3.7.0 (default, Jun 28 2018, 08:04:48) [MSC v.1912 64 bit (AMD64)]
but when i open python the version shown is 3.7.4, is it because i choose version 3.7 in anaconda that will change the python version? thank you so much

Comment: btw the code I was using was also from the tutorial: https://github.com/aladdinpersson/Machine-Learning-Collection/blob/master/ML/TensorFlow/Basics/tutorial4-convnet.py

Comment: This code will not run on Python 3.7.0, you need to be using 3.7.4.

Comment: What's the output of `python -c "import sys, typing;print(sys.version, \"\n\", \"OrderedDict\" in dir(typing), \"\nDone.\n\")`

Comment: @CristiFati i did that and got "3.7.4 (tags/v3.7.4:e09359112e, Jul  8 2019, 20:34:20) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]" in cmd and i just updated my anaconda python version to 3.7.4 and now it shows 3.7.4, now this works thanks guys!
however now it does not detect my gpu even tho I installed cuda and cdnn

Comment: Maybe the last *URL* in my answer could help with *GPU*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [[Python.docs]: class typing.OrderedDict(collections.OrderedDict, MutableMapping[KT, VT])](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/typing.html#typing.OrderedDict) (**emphasis** is mine):

> ***New in version 3.7.2**.*

Example:

> ```
> (base) [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q075529492]> sopr.bat
> ### Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ###
>
> [prompt]> conda env list
> # conda environments:
> #
>                          F:\Install\pc032\Intel\OneAPI\Version\intelpython\python3.7
>                          F:\Install\pc032\Intel\OneAPI\Version\intelpython\python3.7\envs\2021.1.1
> base                  *  f:\Install\pc064\Anaconda\Anaconda\Version
> py_pc032_03_06_02        f:\Install\pc064\Anaconda\Anaconda\Version\envs\py_pc032_03_06_02
> py_pc064_03_06_02        f:\Install\pc064\Anaconda\Anaconda\Version\envs\py_pc064_03_06_02
> py_pc064_03_07_04        f:\Install\pc064\Anaconda\Anaconda\Version\envs\py_pc064_03_07_04
> py_pc064_03_08_08        f:\Install\pc064\Anaconda\Anaconda\Version\envs\py_pc064_03_08_08
> py_pc064_03_10_00        f:\Install\pc064\Anaconda\Anaconda\Version\envs\py_pc064_03_10_00
> py_pc064_03_10_06        f:\Install\pc064\Anaconda\Anaconda\Version\envs\py_pc064_03_10_06
>
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> conda activate py_pc064_03_07_04
>
> (py_pc064_03_07_04) [prompt]>
> (py_pc064_03_07_04) [prompt]> python -c "import sys, typing;print(\"{:}\n{:}\nDone.\n\".format(sys.version, \"OrderedDict\" in dir(typing)"))
> 3.7.4 (default, Aug  9 2019, 18:34:13) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)]
> True
> Done.
> ```

There it is: *Python 3.7.4* from *Anaconda*, whose *typing* module has *OrderedDict*.
The only logical conclusion (well, excluding a broken environment with an messed up *typing* version) one could draw is that you're actually running ***Python < v3.7.2***.
The fix is **running *Python >= v3.7.2***.

Might want to also check:

- [[SO]: PyCharm doesn't recognize installed module (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73363599/4788546)
- [[SO]: On Windows, running "import tensorflow" generates No module named "_pywrap_tensorflow" error (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57855072/4788546)