# how to solve scipy importerror

Tags: python, scipy, anaconda, pywin32

I have run into a problem while importing Scipy.

My OS is windows 10 enterprise. I have installed the latest Anaconda package (2022-10 64bit) in Jan of 2023. Everything was fine. And today I found I have trouble to run some code I created a few weeks ago. The problem is with SciPy. For example, with

```
from scipy import optimize
```

I got error

> ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _interpolative: The
> specified procedure could not be found.

It happens to other Scipy modules such as `scipy.integrate`

From what I can remember, the only change I made recently was to install `pywin32`. Not sure if this is relevant. Also not sure if my company IT did any update to my system.

I have uninstalled Anaconda and reinsall twice. It did not help... Can anyone here help me out? Thank you very much.

P.S. following the suggestions from the replies, I tried

```
print(sys.executable)
print(sys.version)
print(os.getcwd())
print(getattr(os, "uname", lambda: None)())
print(sys.path)
```

And below is the results I got

> C:\Users\span\Anaconda3\python.exe
> 3.9.13 (main, Aug 25 2022, 23:51:50) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
> C:\Users\span
> None
> ['C:\Users\span', 'C:\Users\span\Anaconda3\python39.zip', 'C:\Users\span\Anaconda3\DLLs', 'C:\Users\span\Anaconda3\lib', 'C:\Users\span\Anaconda3', '', 'C:\Users\span\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages', 'C:\Users\span\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages', 'C:\Users\span\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32', 'C:\Users\span\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32\lib', 'C:\Users\span\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin', 'C:\Users\span\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\extensions', 'C:\Users\span\.ipython']

Comment: Could you run `import os` and `print(os.executable)` and see what path it prints out? It's possible you are not using the Anaconda python, but a different python executable.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I checked and it seems to be the right executable. C:\Users\ABC\Anaconda3\python.exe

Comment: Add the whole traceback. [\[SO\]: PyCharm doesn't recognize installed module (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73363599/4788546)

Comment: Tried but did not see anything wrong. Results updated in the main post

Comment: Partly solved the problem by creating a new environment with only script installed. But th

Comment: Partly solved the problem by creating a new environment and work under it.