# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'googletrans', but I did download it

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, modulenotfounderror, googletrans

I'm trying to test out googletrans every time I try to run the file I get this error message:

```py
from googletrans import Translator
```

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'googletrans'.

I have tried uninstalling googletrans and reinstalling it. When I try to install it this is what I get:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip install googletrans==4.0.0rc1
Collecting googletrans==4.0.0rc1
  Using cached googletrans-4.0.0rc1-py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: httpx==0.13.3 in c:\users\arbik\appdata\local\programs\python\python312\lib\site-packages (from googletrans==4.0.0rc1) (0.13.3)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi in c:\users\arbik\appdata\local\programs\python\python312\lib\site-packages (from httpx==0.13.3->googletrans==4.0.0rc1) (2023.11.17)
Requirement already satisfied: hstspreload in c:\users\arbik\appdata\local\programs\python\python312\lib\site-packages (from httpx==0.13.3->googletrans==4.0.0rc1) (2023.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: sniffio in c:\users\arbik\appdata\local\programs\python\python312\lib\site-packages (from httpx==0.13.3->googletrans==4.0.0rc1) (1.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet==3.* in c:\users\arbik\appdata\local\programs\python\python312\lib\site-packages (from httpx==0.13.3->googletrans==4.0.0rc1) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: idna==2.* in c:\users\arbik\appdata\local\programs\python\python312\lib\site-packages (from httpx==0.13.3->googletrans==4.0.0rc1) (2.10)
Requirement already satisfied: rfc3986<2,>=1.3 in c:\users\arbik\appdata\local\programs\python\python312\lib\site-packages (from httpx==0.13.3->googletrans==4.0.0rc1) (1.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: httpcore==0.9.* in c:\users\arbik\appdata\local\programs\python\python312\lib\site-packages (from httpx==0.13.3->googletrans==4.0.0rc1) (0.9.1)
Requirement already satisfied: h11<0.10,>=0.8 in c:\users\arbik\appdata\local\programs\python\python312\lib\site-packages (from httpcore==0.9.*->httpx==0.13.3->googletrans==4.0.0rc1) (0.9.0)
Requirement already satisfied: h2==3.* in c:\users\arbik\appdata\local\programs\python\python312\lib\site-packages (from httpcore==0.9.*->httpx==0.13.3->googletrans==4.0.0rc1) (3.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: hyperframe<6,>=5.2.0 in c:\users\arbik\appdata\local\programs\python\python312\lib\site-packages (from h2==3.*->httpcore==0.9.*->httpx==0.13.3->googletrans==4.0.0rc1) (5.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: hpack<4,>=3.0 in c:\users\arbik\appdata\local\programs\python\python312\lib\site-packages (from h2==3.*->httpcore==0.9.*->httpx==0.13.3->googletrans==4.0.0rc1) (3.0.0)
Installing collected packages: googletrans
Successfully installed googletrans-4.0.0rc1
```

I'm using Pycharm Community 2023.3.

I tried uninstalling googletrans and reinstalling it.

Comment: Try installing using `python -m pip install googletrans` and running your Python file with `python file.py`.

Comment: Check what Python version PyCharm shows, it's very well possible it uses a different one from the v3.12 you have installed googletrans for.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PyCharm doesn't recognize installed module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31235376/pycharm-doesnt-recognize-installed-module)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try an older version of python or googlettrans, some modules only work on specific python versions.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).