# No module named win32com.client

Tags: python

My System has Win 7 64bit installed when I try to execute the below code I'm facing with the error "No module named win32com.client". Can anyone help me with that?

```
import wmi
c = wmi.WMI()
display = c.Win32_videocontroller
print display.properties
```

I'm using Python 2.7Ver

Error code:

> Traceback (most recent call last):  File "", line 1, in
>     import wmi  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\wmi.py",
>   line 88, in   from win32com.client import GetObject, Dispatch

ImportError: **No module named win32com.client**

Comment: try `pip install pywin32`

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23864234/importerror-no-module-named-win32com-client).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ImportError: No module named win32com.client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23864234/importerror-no-module-named-win32com-client)

Answer (score 12):

UPDATE 2016

There is now a version of pywin32 on PyPI that can be installed with pip. It is called pypiwin32, and it installs the package using the binary wheel format.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pypiwin32

```
    pip install pypiwin32
```

That will work in a virtualenv, or with tox, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can google it.[Visit this link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/) and choose the right version to install on your computer。

Answer (score 0):

[Go To this link](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pywin32)

Then use

```
$python setup.py install
```

Answer (score -1):

As of 2020, [Python 2 is unsupported.](https://www.infoworld.com/article/3365221/python-2-end-of-life-how-to-survive-the-end-of-python-2.html)

Also, the package named [`pypiwin32`](https://pypi.org/project/pypiwin32/) looks abandoned as it lags behind in version (221 vs [224](https://pypi.org/project/pywin32/)) and lacks a description.

`python -m pip install pywin32` works in Python 3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:06:47) [MSC v.1914 32 bit (Intel)] on win32 on Windows 10, and Python 3.8.6 (tags/v3.8.6:db45529, Sep 23 2020, 15:52:53) [MSC v.1927 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32 on Windows 10 Pro, but if it doesn't for you:

[Install the pywin32 package](https://superuser.com/a/1329256/103551):

1. Start a command line with admin rights.
2. `python -m pip install pywin32`
3. `python %LOCALAPPDATA%\Programs\Python\Python312\Scripts\pywin32_postinstall.py -install` or thereabouts.