# Installing the pypiwin32 module

Tags: python, win32com

I get this error when I run a program:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-b045b37982bc> in <module>()
      4 #speech recognition
      5 import speech_recognition as sr
----> 6 import win32com.client
      7 import comtypes.client
      8 #speech synthesis

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32com'

---------------------------------------------------
```

When I tried to install the `pypiwin32` module, I got this error:

```
 Collecting pypiwin32
  Using cached pypiwin32-223-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pywin32>=223 (from pypiwin32)
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32>=223 (from pypiwin32) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pywin32>=223 (from pypiwin32)
```

Comment: I haven't used it in a long time, but at least a few years ago,  you couldn't install `pywin32` via `pip` (partly because it requires running a post-install script with elevated privs even if you install into a user-writable location); you had to go to Mark Hammond's site to download and run the installer.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `pypiwin32` depends on [`pywin32`](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32), and, as the README says:

> Note that PIP support is experimental.

Even if `pip` installs `pywin32`, you still have to manually run the post-install script with elevated privileges. So, rather than debugging why the experimental `pip` support isn't working for you, it's probably better to manually download the appropriate installer from the [Releases](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/releases) page and run it.

Once that completes, `pip` should know that you now have `pywin32` version 223 installed, so `pip install pypiwin32` should hopefully work.

You might want to look through the [`pywin32` issues](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/issues) to see if anyone has reported this problem (it may only be mentioned in some issue about completing `pip` support, not a separate one) and, if not, file a bug report. That way, the next time someone wants to use `pypiwin32`, they may not even need this answer. (Since Mark Hammond, the main author of `pywin32`, is also listed as a maintainer of `pypiwin32`, I'm guessing he already knows about it—but it can't hurt to check.)