# Cannot install pypwin32 in google colab

Tags: python, pypi

I am currently using google collaboratory and I cannot install the pypiwin32 library. I have tried using,

```
!pip install pypiwin32
```

Then I have ended up with the following error. Can someone explain the issue here?

```
Collecting pypiwin32
  Using cached pypiwin32-223-py3-none-any.whl (1.7 kB)
  Using cached pypiwin32-219.zip (4.8 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/2b/ca/5c086c18de8f70222787b3e824e755b68d99272531522e77bb381d4f60c8/pypiwin32-219.zip#sha256=06d478295c89dbdd4187e1ac099bb8eab93c29e298bded4e2fbc77009287fa44 (from https://pypi.org/simple/pypiwin32/). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32>=223 (from pypiwin32) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pywin32>=223
```

Comment: Surely you don't need pypiwin32 on google collaboratory as it does not run on windows?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installing the pypiwin32 module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49307303/installing-the-pypiwin32-module)