# Unable to install pypiwin32 library

Tags: python, machine-learning, pywin32

Tried to install the `pip install pypiwin32` in Google Colab for reading outlook emails. But the installation keeps on getting failed.

[image]

Tried by downgrading the python version to 3.9 as well, but didn't worked.

Any suggestions for fixing the issue?

Comment: You want https://pypi.org/project/pywin32/#files. *PyPiWin32* is garbage. https://stackoverflow.com/q/49307303/4788546.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Are you running it actually on Windows? If no, it pyiwin32 only is supported for Windows
- Try using `pip install --no-cache-dir pyiwin32`

Comment: It is working fine jupyter notebook in windows. But how can I fix it in colab?? I tried it but not working in colab

Comment: I think google colab runs on ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Tried installing `!pip install pypiwin32` in Jupyter notebook, it works like a charm.

But didn't worked in colab.

Comment: What type of compute did it work like a charm on? Minor point: You'll have better luck going forward with Jupyter using the magic install and not the exclamation point. `%pip install pypiwin32`. The magic command insures the installation occurs in the proper environment that the kernel underlying the notebook is using. The exclamation point alone doesn't do that & can lead to issues sometimes.  See [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez) for more about the modern `%pip install` magic command. (Also a conda one, too.)

Comment: I see Kalliii pointed this out above 10 days agao, but still you wrote today that it didn't work in colab. You aren't going to get it to work colab as that is a linux based system that underlies Google Colab.