# How can i delete files in a folder and subfolders using python in windows machine?

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7

I want to delete all the files older than one day except the hidden files

I have tried the below code but it seems it also tries to delete hidden files, how can I modify it so that it deletes all the files but not hidden files?

```
import os
import time

current_time = time.time()

for f in os.listdir():
    creation_time = os.path.getctime(f)
    if (current_time - creation_time) // (24 * 3600) >= 1:
        os.unlink(f)
        print('{} removed'.format(f))
```

If it was linux, I could have done,

```
if not f.startswith('.'):
```

I have gone through the links:  https://bitbucket.org/aafshar/pida-main/src/tip/pida/services/filemanager/filemanager.py

I do not probably understand it. A more simple code would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a code-writing service

Comment: I did not get you? How is it off topic? @DeepSpace

Comment: See [ask]......

Comment: Can u suggest how i can ask it differently? It is my first question

Comment: For starters, show your attempt

Comment: Don't ask "I want to do X, please give me teh codez"; ask "I want to do X. I tried Y. My code does this part correctly, but this other part doesn't work because Z. I did research on the topic and found these relevant resources (A, B), but I still can't figure out the solution." In other words, show us that you've made an attempt to solve the problem. This problem consists of 4 smaller problems: Listing all files in a folder, checking if the file is older than a day, checking if it's a hidden file, and deleting it. Surely you can solve one or two of those problems without our help?

Comment: I have edited it now

Comment: See [Cross platform hidden file detection](//stackoverflow.com/q/284115) to find out how to check if a file is hidden, and [How do I list all files of a directory?](//stackoverflow.com/q/3207219) or [Browse files and subfolders in Python](//stackoverflow.com/q/5817209) to find out how to iterate over files in subfolders.

Comment: Hi, i have gone through those links but i was not able to implement it, after spending 1 and half day i thought of asking it in SO. Could you please help me out?

Comment: Can u remove the downvotes?

Comment: wait for it, i am working on the code

Answer (score 0):

This code is for windows file system, i didnt check the unlink part(which is correct, my assumption ): code explain in the code comments. btw 24 * 3600 == 86400 ( 24 hours in seconds)

```
import os
import time

import win32file
import win32con

from datetime import datetime

#convert float to datetime obj, current time
current_time = datetime.strptime(time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.localtime(time.time())),'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

for f in os.listdir():
    #file's time to datetime object
    creation_time = datetime.strptime(time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.localtime(os.path.getctime(f))),'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    #subtract both the time -->timedelta object
    z= current_time - creation_time

    #get windows attribute for the file
    file_flag = win32file.GetFileAttributesW(f)
    #check the attribute value for files in windows, for hidden files the attribute should be '2'
    is_hidden = file_flag & win32con.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN

    if ((z.seconds >= 86400) and (is_hidden != 2)):  
        os.unlink(f)
        print('{} removed'.format(f))
```

windows file system code reference : [link](https://www.programering.com/a/MDM5EjMwATM.html)

Comment: I am getting error:  no module file win32file . I am using python 2.7

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23864234/importerror-no-module-named-win32com-client , for python 2.7 you can refer this link.

Comment: i have anaconda for python 3 installed and it works without any installation. you can you that or refer the link which i gave.

Comment: please upvote and mark the answer if you use it. thank you