# PyInstaller "failed to execute script" Error

Tags: python, python-2.7, compiler-errors, exe, pyinstaller

I'm trying to make an exe file with PyInstaller however I'm unable to do so. The file is built and deposited in the dist folder, however when I try to run it, the the error "Failed to execute script {name}" pops up.

Here is the .spec file that I'm using:

```py
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['simulator.pyw'],
             pathex=['C:\\Simulator'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[('bin/**/*.kv', './bin/ui'), ('bin/**/*.xml', './bin/ui')],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=True,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          [],
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='simulator',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=False , icon='bin\\ui\\icon.ico')
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               upx_exclude=[],
               name='simulator')
```

and this is the output from the console:

[LOG](https://pastebin.com/4UN8788G)

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problems seemed to be indeed in Kivy (https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/packaging-windows.html#alternate-installations). I modified the .spec file and the application was built successfully.

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['simulator.pyw'],
             pathex=['C:\\Python27\\Scripts\\Simulator'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[('./bin/ui/dynamic_classes.kv', './bin/ui/'), ('./bin/ui/main_layout.kv', './bin/ui/'), ('./bin/ui/text.xml', './bin/ui/'), ('./bin/ui/treatment_adaptive.kv', './bin/ui/'), ('./bin/ui/treatment_classic.kv', './bin/ui/'), ('./bin/ui/treatment_user.kv', './bin/ui/'), ('./bin/ui/icon.ico', './bin/ui/')],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=True,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          [],
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='simulator',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          clean=True,
          console=False, icon='bin\\ui\\icon.ico')
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               Tree('C:\\Python27\\share\\sdl2\\bin'),
               Tree('C:\\Python27\\share\\glew\\bin'),
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               upx_exclude=[],
               name='simulator')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check the full traceback by starting the script via command prompt.

This can be done by pressing `WIN` + `R` and writting `cmd` then changing the directory with `cd command` until you reach the folder, and then use `.\<softwarename>.exe` to run.

For example:

```
> cd C:\softwares\test
> pwd
C:\softwares\test
> .\test.exe
```

From experience, this probably is caused by a `ModuleNotFoundError`. If that's the problem you can add the module name to the `hiddenimports` list at the spec.

i.e.: `hiddenimports=['pyodbc'],`

Answer (score 0):

So you are using Kivy and it logs several errors:

```
picamera - ImportError: No module named picamera
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\__init__.py", line 63, in core_select_lib
    fromlist=[modulename], level=0)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\camera\camera_picamera.py", line 18, in <module>
    from picamera import PiCamera

gi - ImportError: No module named gi.repository
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\__init__.py", line 63, in core_select_lib
    fromlist=[modulename], level=0)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\camera\camera_gi.py", line 10, in <module>
    from gi.repository import Gst

opencv - ImportError: No module named cv2
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\__init__.py", line 63, in core_select_lib
    fromlist=[modulename], level=0)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\camera\camera_opencv.py", line 48, in <module>
    import cv2
```

Did you declare kivy in a requirements.txt file ?

There is also

```
15333 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook   win32com
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
ImportError: No module named win32com
15411 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook   win32com
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
ImportError: No module named win32com
```

which says a library is missing (see [ImportError: No module named win32com.client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23864234/importerror-no-module-named-win32com-client)).

So, how did you declare the dependencies ? We'd need to see your project structure.