# What is the right module to download Outlook attachments with a Python script?

Tags: python, windows, pywin32, win32com

I want to automate downloading attachments from emails going into my Outlook account. In previous sample code I see people using the module `win32com.client`. When I look for modules to install from Pycharm I only see `win32compat`. Will `win32compat` give me the methods I need, or am I missing something? I also see people using `pypiwin32` and `pywin32`.

Comment: It should be inside `pywin32`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23864234/importerror-no-module-named-win32com-client