# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pywin32'

Tags: python, anaconda

I am using Python 3.8.0 and on windows 10 64-bit.
I'm trying to unprotect an excel spreadsheet using the import win32com. This isn't recognised but I followed solution provided on [ImportError: No module named win32com.client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23864234/importerror-no-module-named-win32com-client)
The pip install pywin32 ran successfully. I've copied Command Prompt info below:

```
C:\Users\PCname>pip install pywin32
Requirement already satisfied: pywin32 in c:\users\PCname\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (227)

C:\Users\PCname>pip show pypiwin32
Name: pypiwin32
Version: 223
Summary: UNKNOWN
Home-page: UNKNOWN
Author: UNKNOWN
Author-email: UNKNOWN
License: UNKNOWN
Location: c:\users\PCname\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages
Requires: pywin32
Required-by:

C:\Users\PCname>pip show win32com
WARNING: Package(s) not found: win32com

C:\Users\PCname>pip install win32com
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement win32com (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for win32com

C:\Users\PCname>pip show pywin32
Name: pywin32
Version: 227
Summary: Python for Window Extensions
Home-page: https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32
Author: Mark Hammond (et al)
Author-email: mhammond@skippinet.com.au
License: PSF
Location: c:\users\pcname\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages
Requires:
Required-by: pypiwin32
```

There seems to be an incorrect pathway but I checked as above and the location is saved in '\python38-32\lib\site-packages'.

Any ideas why Python 3.8.0 Shell returns 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named' for each module??

```
>>> import pywin32
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    import pywin32
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pywin32'
>>> import pypiwin32
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    import pypiwin32
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pypiwin32'
>>> import win32com
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    import win32com
  File "C:\Users\PCname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\win32com\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    import win32api, sys, os
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32api'
```

Perhaps my recent uninstall of Anaconda still affects my future pip install modules on Command Prompt?
If so, do I need to redefine pip install pathway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no module by name pywin32 in pywin32 package. You need to import the win32com.client in your code.
    import win32com.client as win32