# Why does installing `pypiwin32` or `pywin32` fail when installing as a dependency but succeed when just using pip on its own?

Tags: python, pip, conda, pywin32, python-packaging

I have  `setup.py` like this:

```
setup(
    name='pyomexmeta',
    version=version,
    license='MIT',
    long_description=open('README.md').read(),
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    author='Ciaran Welsh',
    author_email='cwelsh2@uw.edu',
    url='https://github.com/sys-bio/libomexmeta',
    keywords=['annotation', 'rdf'],
    # install_requires=open('requirements.txt').read().split('\n'),
    install_requires=["pypiwin32"],
    packages=['pyomexmeta'],
    package_dir={'pyomexmeta': 'src/pyomexmeta'},
    package_data={'pyomexmeta': [
        'LICENCE.txt',
    ] + binaries},
    include_package_data=True,
    classifiers=[_f for _f in CLASSIFIERS.split('\n') if _f],
    platforms=["Windows", "Linux", "Unix"],  # "Mac OS-X", - not yet supported.
)
```

The important part for this question in `install_requires=['pypiwin32']`. When I try to install my package from `testpypi` inside a fresh conda environment I get an error:

```
PS D:\libOmexMeta> conda create -y --name omex python=3.7
PS D:\libOmexMeta> conda activate omex
PS D:\libOmexMeta> pip install --index-url https://test.pypi.org/simple/ pyomexmeta
```

The error I get is this:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pypiwin32 (from pyomexmeta) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pypiwin32 (from pyomexmeta)
```

yet, when I do

```
 PS D:\libOmexMeta> pip install pypiwin32
```

it installs without fail.

Anybody know what's going on here?

Note, same thing happenes with `pywin32`.

Comment: What version of pip are you on? If you upgrade with `pip install --upgrade pip`, do you get a more helpful message? If you pass `-v` to the failing command, do you get any useful debugging info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before everything, check [[SO]: ImportError: No module named win32com.client (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75310161/4788546) regarding *PyPIWin32*.

Listing [[PyPA.PIP]: pip install](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install).

By passing `--index-url https://test.pypi.org/simple`, you changed *PIP*'s (default) repository, to the one given as argument. But that seems to be broken for *PyPIWin32* ([[PyPI.Test]: Links for pypiwin32](https://test.pypi.org/simple/pypiwin32)).
*PyWin32* isn't even listed there.

On the other hand, in `pip install pypiwin32`'s case, it used the default repository where it found the package and things went fine.

**Test**:

> ```bat
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q062697213]> sopr.bat
> ### Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ###
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> :: Search default repo
> [prompt]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.07.06_test0\Scripts\python.exe" -m pip -v search pypiwin32
> Getting credentials from keyring for pypi.org
> Starting new HTTPS connection (1): pypi.org:443
> https://pypi.org:443 "POST /pypi HTTP/1.1" 200 200
> pypiwin32 (223)  -
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> :: Search custom repo
> [prompt]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.07.06_test0\Scripts\python.exe" -m pip -v search -i https://test.pypi.org/simple pypiwin32
> Getting credentials from keyring for test.pypi.org
> Starting new HTTPS connection (1): test.pypi.org:443
> https://test.pypi.org:443 "POST /simple HTTP/1.1" 301 205
> Looking up "https://test.pypi.org/simple/" in the cache
> Current age based on date: 134
> Freshness lifetime from max-age: 600
> The response is "fresh", returning cached response
> 600 > 134
> ERROR: Exception:
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.07.06_test0\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 186, in _main
>     status = self.run(options, args)
>   File "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.07.06_test0\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\search.py", line 52, in run
>     pypi_hits = self.search(query, options)
>   File "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.07.06_test0\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\search.py", line 71, in search
>     hits = pypi.search({'name': query, 'summary': query}, 'or')
>   File "c:\Install\pc064\Python\Python\03.07.06\Lib\xmlrpc\client.py", line 1112, in __call__
>     return self.__send(self.__name, args)
>   File "c:\Install\pc064\Python\Python\03.07.06\Lib\xmlrpc\client.py", line 1452, in __request
>     verbose=self.__verbose
>   File "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.07.06_test0\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\network\xmlrpc.py", line 38, in request
>     return self.parse_response(response.raw)
>   File "c:\Install\pc064\Python\Python\03.07.06\Lib\xmlrpc\client.py", line 1342, in parse_response
>     return u.close()
>   File "c:\Install\pc064\Python\Python\03.07.06\Lib\xmlrpc\client.py", line 654, in close
>     raise ResponseError()
> xmlrpc.client.ResponseError: ResponseError()
> ```

To get past your problem, either:

- Since you already installed the dependencies, don't try to install them by passing ***--no-deps***: `pip install --no-deps --index-url https://test.pypi.org/simple pyomexmeta`
- Specify additional repositories (the default one), by passing ***--extra-index-url*** (! didn't test it !)

Check the notes from [[GitHub]: sys-bio/libOmexMeta - sys-bio.github.io/libsemsim-docs](https://github.com/sys-bio/libOmexMeta).

You might also want to take a look at [[Anaconda]: Using Pip in a Conda Environment](https://www.anaconda.com/blog/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment).

Comment: Well I never would have figured that one out ha thanks for the answer. Note, that libsemsim/omexmeta is the library I'm writing/testing and I'm only half way through writing the docs - so probably not much good info there :P The important thing is that this will be fixed and will work fine when I publish to pypi (not pypi test) - so I can basically do nothing for now.

Comment: Lol, I didn't look at the repo owner :).  That's correct!