# I tried installing win32gui using pip but I'm getting this error. I am using python 3.8.5, I have latest version of pip too

Tags: python, pip, win32gui

```
C:\Users\Viraj Sharma>pip install win32gui
Collecting win32gui
  Using cached win32gui-221.5.tar.gz (605 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\viraj sharma\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' 'c:\users\viraj sharma\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' get_requires_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\VIRAJS~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpjn8lvta1'
       cwd: C:\Users\Viraj Sharma\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-gcbm1r68\win32gui
  Complete output (20 lines):
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "c:\users\viraj sharma\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py", line 280, in <module>
      main()
    File "c:\users\viraj sharma\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py", line 263, in main
      json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
    File "c:\users\viraj sharma\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py", line 114, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
      return hook(config_settings)
    File "C:\Users\Viraj Sharma\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-9wmd0fza\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 149, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
      return self._get_build_requires(
    File "C:\Users\Viraj Sharma\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-9wmd0fza\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 130, in _get_build_requires
      self.run_setup()
    File "C:\Users\Viraj Sharma\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-9wmd0fza\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 253, in run_setup
      super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend,
    File "C:\Users\Viraj Sharma\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-9wmd0fza\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 145, in run_setup
      exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
    File "setup.py", line 27, in <module>
      from win32.distutils.gui import win32gui_build_ext
    File "C:\Users\Viraj Sharma\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-gcbm1r68\win32gui\win32\distutils\gui.py", line 6, in <module>
      from .command import win32_build_ext
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32.distutils.command'
  ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\viraj sharma\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' 'c:\users\viraj sharma\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' get_requires_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\VIRAJS~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpjn8lvta1' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: No module named win32com.client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23864234/importerror-no-module-named-win32com-client)

Answer (score 0):

Python 3.7 or 3.8 aren't compatible with win32gui.

3.8 was released in 2019 and the latest version of win32gui was released in August 2017.

I suggest using python 3.6 or lower for the installiton to work properly.

But, theres an alternative, by installing (pip install pywin32) will install win32gui alongside modules for interfacing with windows.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below command to install win32gui.

```
pip install pywin32
```