# Error when using winshell module: No module named 'win32'

Tags: python, pip, compiler-errors, pywin32, python-winshell

```py
import winshell

r = list(winshell.recycle_bin())

for index, value in enumerate(r):
    print(index, value.original_filename())
```

This is the simple script I wrote, but when I try running it (or antyhing else that uses winshell) I get this error:
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32'`

And when I try running `pip install win32` I get another error:

`ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement win32 (from versions: none)`
`ERROR: No matching distribution found for win32`

So now I'm even more confused. Why does winshell need a different module? That module doesn't even exist. Is it fine if I use some different module than the non-existent win32? If so which one? What am I supposed to do now?

Comment: You do realize the module is no longer maintained. Did you install *PyWin32* (`python -m pip install pywin32` (or `pip install pywin32`))? https://stackoverflow.com/a/75310161/4788546.

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to execute the script inside the Scripts directory, the pywin32_postinstall.py. Let’s say your Python directory is C:\python3, just follow the code below.

```
cd C:\python3
python Scripts/pywin32_postinstall.py -install
```

After that, the installation will drop the DLL files under the `C:\Windows\System32`. You need to move those two files ( pythoncom310.dll and pywintypes310.dll) to `C:\python3\Lib\site-packages\win32` directory.

After that, you need to edit the python310._pth that you can find inside the Python installation folder. Then make the following changes:

```
Lib/site-packages
Lib/site-packages/win32
Lib/site-packages/win32/lib
Lib/site-packages/pythonwin
python310.zip

#Uncomment to run site.main() automatically
#import site
```

Save and try running your code again.

> Troubleshoot

If you still get an error saying “ImportError: DLL load failed while importing win32api: The specified module could not be found.”, make sure you have copied the two dll files to `Lib\site-packages\win32 directory`.
PythonWin32Api