I can't install pywin32
I'm trying to get this program to run:
https://github.com/GavriloviciEduard/ShinyHunter
But I get this error message:
C:\Users\marku\ShinyHunter>python -m poetry install
Installing dependencies from lock file

Package operations: 1 install, 0 updates, 0 removals

  - Installing pywin32 (304): Failed

  RuntimeError

  Unable to find installation candidates for pywin32 (304)

  at ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\poetry\installation\chooser.py:74 in choose_for
       70│
       71│             links.append(link)
       72│
       73│         if not links:
    →  74│             raise RuntimeError(f"Unable to find installation candidates for {package}")
       75│
       76│         # Get the best link
       77│         chosen = max(links, key=lambda link: self._sort_key(package, link))
       78│

Cannot install pywin32.

This message came when I tried: python -m pip install pywin32
C:\Users\marku\ShinyHunter>python -m pip install pywin32
Requirement already satisfied: pywin32 in c:\users\marku\appdata\local\programs\python\python312\lib\site-packages (306)

C:\Users\marku\ShinyHunter>python -m poetry run python src\main.py --help
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\marku\ShinyHunter\src\main.py", line 4, in <module>
    from shunter.stationary import ShinyHunterStationary
  File "C:\Users\marku\ShinyHunter\src\shunter\stationary.py", line 3, in <module>
    from shunter.abstract.abstract_shiny_hunter import AbstractShinyHunter
  File "C:\Users\marku\ShinyHunter\src\shunter\abstract\abstract_shiny_hunter.py", line 7, in <module>
    from utils.color_point_picker import ColorPointPicker
  File "C:\Users\marku\ShinyHunter\src\utils\color_point_picker.py", line 6, in <module>
    from utils.window_capture import WindowCapture
  File "C:\Users\marku\ShinyHunter\src\utils\window_capture.py", line 5, in <module>
    import win32com.client
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32com'

What should I do?

Try doing python -m pip install pywin32.  You have the very most recent Python (3.12), but pywin32 version 304 came out several years ago.  There could be a version issue.

I tried it, but it already existed, and when I continued, it didn't find win32com (I edited my post)

Try pip install pypiwin32 as per an answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/50741042/17620209

Unfortunately it was already installed
C:\Users\marku\ShinyHunter>pip install pypiwin32
Requirement already satisfied: pypiwin32 in c:\users\marku\appdata\local\programs\python\python312\lib\site-packages (223)
Requirement already satisfied: pywin32>=223 in c:\users\marku\appdata\local\programs\python\python312\lib\site-packages (from pypiwin32) (306)

If the instructions on https://github.com/GavriloviciEduard/ShinyHunter don't work, then the first thing to do is file an issue on their issue tracker to make them aware of that, so they can ammend/change the documentation. That way you're helping everyone, not just people who happen to search Stackoverflow.

Do NOT install pypywin32 (that's just garbage). Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/75310161/4788546 for more details.

According to the readme of pywin32 there is a post installation script to run python Scripts/pywin32_postinstall.py -install.
You can also try updating pip and setup Tools:
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
python -m pip install --upgrade setuptools

Then, upgrade pywin32: python -m pip install --upgrade pywin32
