# No module named 'win32.com', But I have install it. How?

Tags: python, excel, image-processing, win32com

I've got a problem regarding the excel2img module library that is about 'win32com'.
I've check the solutions at link follows:

https://superuser.com/questions/609447/how-to-install-the-win32com-python-library

[Still getting an error "ImportError: No module named win32com.client" after installing pywin32 lib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7978510/still-getting-an-error-importerror-no-module-named-win32com-client-after-inst)

[ImportError: No module named win32com.client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23864234/importerror-no-module-named-win32com-client?newreg=98c5381871aa41d0a72a36f86786bcb9)

However, the error still there.

'''Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Lenovo/PycharmProjects/HO_P1/excelToImage.py", line 4, in 
import excel2img
File "C:\Users\Lenovo\PycharmProjects\HO_P1\venv\lib\site-packages\excel2img_*init*_.py", line 1, in 
from .excel2img import export_img
File "C:\Users\Lenovo\PycharmProjects\HO_P1\venv\lib\site-packages\excel2img\excel2img.py", line 18, in 
import win32com.client
File "C:\Users\Lenovo\PycharmProjects\HO_P1\venv\lib\site-packages\win32com_*init*_.py", line 1, in 
from win32.com import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32.com'
'''
[image shows that I've install the module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4pr4.png)

Can anyone give me a suggestion to solve this problem?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Did you accidentally misspell the module name?

It's

```
from win32com import *
```

Not

```
from win32.com import *
```

Answer (score 0):

you maybe installed more lib than you really need and the additional lib creates this reference error

try to only keep pywin32 and uninstall other lib with win32 in the name